# CGCC Rocket Biking

Tags: code-golf, balanced-string

Something I found while looking through some old files. It seemed like a neat idea for a code golf challenge.

### The intro

One of the most popular events at the annual Cyclist's Grand Competition for Charity (CGCC) is the rocket bike parcours. The rules are simple: Inspect the parcours and place a bet on wheather is it possible to reach and exactly stop on the finish line. The drivers who bet that it's possible then have to prove it to win. If they can't prove it, the drivers who bet against it win.

### The parcours

The rules for the parcours are as follows:

- A parcours consists of uphills, downhills and flat bits. In the examples, it's modelled as a sequence of `/`, `\` and `_` respectively.
- The bike starts with a speed of 0 m/s (i.e. before the first character of the sequence).
- The down-/uphills accelerate/decelerate the bike by 1 m/s.
- On the flat bits the driver must either speed up or slow down manually, again, by 1 m/s. They mustn't do nothing.
- If the bike has a speed of 0 m/s at the finish line (i.e. after the last character of the sequence), the parcours was driven correctly.
- The finish line must be reached.
- The speed must remain >= 0 at all times. If it is/becomes 0 at any point, the next piece of the parcours must accelerate the bike, either through a downhill `\` or through a flat bit `_` where the driver accelerates.

### The task

Given such a parcours, take it as the input for a first program and output whether it's possible or not to drive the parcours correctly according to the rules above. If yes, take the sequence as an input for a second program and output a sequence of instructions for the driver on what to do on the flat bits. In the examples, `+` and `-` are used to signalize acceleration and deceleration respectively.

### The rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). The shortest answer wins.
- Submit one or two program/s that validate the parcours (validator) and generate the instructions for the driver if valid (generator). If two programs are submitted, they are scored seperately and independently from the one program submissions.
- The I/O format may be freely chosen. All characters may be substituted freely.
- The generator program only needs to work on parcours that can be driven correctly.
- The input length is not bounded.

### The examples

Input is taken

```
Input: 
  \_///

Formatted for clarity:
      /
     /
  \_/

Validator output: 
  Falsy (The driver will come to a stop before the last uphill)
```

```
Input: 
  \_\__/

Formatted: 
  \_
    \__/

Validator output:
  Truthy

Generator output:
  --+
```

```
Input: 
  \_\_\

Formatted:
  \_
    \_
      \

Validator output: 
  Falsy (The driver will finish the parcours with at least 1 m/s)
```

## More examples:

**Invalid:**

```
/_/\       (Driver can't go uphill with a speed of 0 at the start)

\/_\\/

/\_\//_\

_\/\///_\\

/__//\/_//_\

/_\\\_\/_/__/\_/_\\\\\_\\/\_\//\\\\/\_///\/__\_\_\/_\\\_\//__//_\__/\\___/_\/_/\_\_/\\\\_\_\_\__\_\\

_/_//_\\//\\\/\/_\/\__\\__//\//_\/_\\\___/\\___\_/\_//\\_\\__\/\\_/_//_/__\/_\\/\\___\_\\\\//_/_\\_\\\_\/\___\_//\\/\\\_/_\///__\//\\\/\\/_\\__\_/\\\/_/_/_//_/_/\\//_\/\/_/\\_\\///_/_\\__/_______\/_///_//_/__//__\_//\\/\\\\\_\\\_\//\_\__/\\\/_\\_\/\_\/_\\_/_\_____/\\_\_/_\/_/\/_/\_\/_\_//_\\//__//\//\//\______\//\_//\/_/\\\/_\__\\/__//\\/\\_\\//_/\\_/_//_\\/\\_/\\/\__/\_\_\\_\_\//__\__\\/_\///___\//\\/\__\/\\\\//__//_/_//\__/\\/___/\\\__\/_\__/_/_/\/\//_\\\/\_/_/_\/__\\_\//___///_/_\//__/\___/_\_/_/\_/_\_/\\\\//\\\\_/_\\/\/__\\/_\_/\//\\_\_\_\_\/_\_//\__\\////////\//_//\//\/\\_/_/___/\/\_\/____/____\\\_///_\_\/\__/\//\_/\\/_/_/\\__\\/\\\\///\//__/\_____\__/\__/\\\__/\\_\/\_\__\/_\\/\_\/\/\\\/_\_\__//_\\/\_\/\\\//\//__\_\_\__\__/\/_\_\_\_/_//\\\\_//\/__\\\\\\___/\/\_\\\\___\\_\\\/\_\__/\_/_/__/__/__\\//_____//_//\___\/\/\/\_\__\__\/_/_/\_//__/\\___/_/_\\/\__\\__\__/\_/_/////\\//\//_\\\\\_\\\\_/\/\_/_//\_/////_///_/\/__\\/_/_\_\/_/\_\__\/\\\_\__/__/_//__\\___/\/\//_\/_\\/\/////__\//_\/__////__\\_//_/\__\/_/__\___//\/\/_/\/\//_\___\/\//\///\/__\_/_/___\/\\_\//__\\\__\/\__//_\\__/\_\/\//\/\__//__/_____\\//__/\\\\\\//_/\_///\/_\\\__/_/\__/\\\//\_\\/\\_\///\_\/\__/\//__\\_\/\\__\__\_/__//\/___\\__/_/_/\__//_//_/\/\_//\//__\\__//\/_///\\\/\__/_\_/__/\__\_/\_/_\\//_/\\/__///\_\/_//\_\\____\_\_\/////_\/_/\\\_//_\_\\\\___/____\/\/_\/_////_\__/_/\/\//_/_\_\__\////\///\_/\/_\____\\//\\__\/\/_\_\_\/\/\\\\/\\__\/_\///\__/\/\\_/_//_//\/\/_////\\\__\\/_/\_/\_\//\/_/_/__\//_\/_\//\\\/\/\_/__\\_\_\//__\_\/_/\/\\\\/__\_/\///\__/____\//\///\_\/\_\/__/\\\__\/\\/\/\_//_/_\_\\__/\/\\_/_\__/\/\/\___\\//_/_\\//__\_\\\\/\_\___/__\\//\\/\_\_\/_/\//\/\/__\_/_______/\_\\__\/_/_/_/\_//__\////\/__//__\/\/\///\_//\/\_//\_//\\_///_/_/__\___\/\/__\\\//__/_\_\_\///_\\_\/_/\\__/_/\\/__/_\/_/_\//\\_\\/__\\\\\/__\______\/_//_/\\\/\/\//_\_//\/\\_\\////\_/\_\\\\/__///_/\\___\/\_\//__//_\__\__/\/\\\/\_/\/_\/_/\__\\/_/\__\/\\/_\\_/\/_\/\_\/\\\\_\_/__\/_/\\\_\/\//\_//\//_/\_/////\\\/__///___/\__//_\\_\\\/\\\___/\/\/\___\____/__////\__\______/__/_//_\\\___//_\_\\\/\\/_/\\_\_/__\__//\/_//_///\//__/\//_/_/_/_/\_\____/_//_____///_\___///_\/__\\/\\//\\_\_\_\_//__//\\__\\_\_/_\//\//\/_\_/_\_//\/\_/_\_/\//_///_/_/\\/_/_/_/_\_\//\_\/\/\/////_/__//\/__\//_\_/__\__\_\_/\\_/_//___/__/_/\///\_\/\/\\__\\\__\/\\/\\/\__//\\\/_/\\/\_\/_//___\\_\/////_\/_\_\__/_//\\\/__/_\\\/\/\_\/__\/\_//\/___/_\\/__\\/_/\\\\/\_//_\/_\/\/\__\\_\\\__\\_/_\///_//_\__/_\_/__///_\__\\_/_\/\___\//_\\_/\\/_/\__/\/_/_\\\\\//_//_\\_///\\\/_\\/\\__\\/__/\_\__\/\//\/_\/\/_\\\/\__\___/_/\/_\\////\\_\___\/\_/__/\/\\__//\//_/_/\\\_/\//\//\/\/_/_\\_/\/\//__/\\/\/_/_\//\/\\_/\//__/\/\////\//__/_/\\\_//_///____//_//\_\/_\_\_\\/\\//__///_\__\/_/_\\/\\\\_\_/\\/_\\_//\\/\\/\\/\_\//_\\//__/_\__/\\_\/\/_/__/\\_\\\_/__/\\\_\_/\___\/_\\//__//_//___\/\/___//_\\___\\/_/_\\_/_\__\/_\_//\_\__/_\//___\\\__//_/__\\\\_/\/\__///____\_/\//_/_\_/___//__\\//\/_/\_\_\\_\//_\_/\_/___\___/\/_//\/_\\\\/\\_____/\/_\/_\_\///_\_/\\//__\__//_/\/\\//___///\\///__\__\////_\\/_/_/_\\\__/\_\/_/_//\_\//_//___/\_/_\\_\_\_///___\/_\__/_/\\/\/_/_\__/_\_/_\__///\\\_/\//_\\_/_\\/\///_\/\__\/_///_\____\/_/\\_//\\_\\_\_\\_\/\\\\\\_\///__\/__\_//\\\/\//__\_\\\_/\/_\_\/\/__/_/\_/\/_\_\__\/_\_//_/\/__\_/_/_//_\/\_\\/_\\\//_\_/\\\\\\_\_/\\/_//_/\_/_/\/\\__/_\/\\\\__/\/_/\//////\\\//\___/_\_//__\__/_/_/_//_\_//\///_\\_\//\\/\//_\_\/\_/_///\\\\_\_\\/_/_\\//\/\/_//\//\_/\_/\\_____/_/\/\/\_\__\///\__\/_/_\\\_\_\___//\__/\_/__//\____/\\\_/\\/__\/_///_//\\_//\__\\_/\/_\_/_\_\\///___/_///\//_/___\///\\\\/\/\\/\___/_/__/\/__/_\_/\/_/\__//_//____\/\\\//_\__/__\_///___///_\//_//__////_\//_//\\___/\/\//_\/_\/\\\\_\//_\\___\_\/_\\\//_\\\/\/\//__\\_\\\_\\\\/___/\/_\____/___//_\\\_/\_\_//_/\_\\_/_\\\__\/_//\\/_/\_/\//_/__////______/\/\/\/_//_\\/\______\__/\/__\__////__/\\__\\_\//__//\_\\\/_//\\_\__\\_/\\/_//\\___/_\///_/\__/_/\///\\//__/_/_/_/////\//\_\\__\_\/\//_/_\\//___/__\/\\___\/\_\__/_/____\__\\____/____/\_/\\///\/\_\\/\\\\//__\//\_//\_/\\_\_/_\/\//\\__\\_//\/_\_/\/_\__/\//\__\/___\__\//\/_\__\__\\//_\_/___/\\_/_//\\\/\/__/_//\/_\_/\/_\/_\/_\\\_//\\__/_//\\/\\_\_\\__/\\\//\__\/\//_\_\/_/_/\___\\\/\\_/\/__\_\_\/\\//_\/\//\_/___/_\\\\\\___/\\_\///\/\_///_//_\_/\\__\__\/_//_\_\\\\/_/__\/\/____/\\\\_\\_/\/_\//_\_\//\_////\/_\___///__\/__/_\/\_//_\\_//_\_\///\/_/\__/__\\_\___//_\____/\///_\/_____\/___/\\\///\/_\/_//__/__/\___\/__//\_///\__///_/_\/_/\_/\_\/\/\\/\///_/_/\\__\_\_\\/\//\\\/\\___//__/_\__/_\\\_\//_/_///\/_///_\//\/\_/\\__\/_\/\_\_\\_\_/__\\_\_\_\__\\__/_\//\_//\_\\//\/___\//__\\/__\\\\//_\_\/_/_/_//_\\_//____\\\_/\\_/_\\\/\\\\\___///\/\__\___\__/_/____/\/_/_\_//\_/\_\___/_/\\_/_\\\\___\/\/\\\/\/\_/___\\_\\\\\\_//////_/_\\\\/\\\\/_\\///\/\/\/\/_\_______/_/\/\/\/_\____\\_\_//\_//__\\\\/\\\\//_\\_/__///_____//\\/_/\\____/__//_\_/__\_\/___\\_\\_/___\////_\__\_\_/_\\\/_\_\/\\_\\/_///\\_//_\_\__/_\/_//_\\///_/\\/\/_\/\_/_//\/\\//\///\\///__/\\//_/\/\_/\_/_\/____/\_\_\//_//_\/\____\_/\\__//\____\\\\__//_\_/_/_/_//\_\\\___\\/\\/\\_///\__\\__\_/_/\/\\__\//\/__/\//_\\__\\__\\\\__\/_\/_/___/\_\\/_\/_\\___///\\_/\_/\__/////_/\\_\_\_//\//\_\__\_\__/__\\//\\_/\\/_\/_/_\/_\/__\\_\\__//\_\__/_/\_\/\_/\////////_///__\_/_\/_/\\\_/\/\\\\/_\\//\////___/_\/\/_\/_/_//___/\/_\__//\///_\//\\//\\//\\___/\\_\\/_/_/\\\/\//\\_\///\__//_\\//\\\_/\/\/\//_///__\_/\\\\\/\\/\\\\\__\\\\\__\_/\\__////\_/\_\/___//_/_/\//\_/\_\\\\/_/_\\/\\/_//\_/\/_\\__//_/_//\/\_/\_\\/_\///_//_///_\/\__\__\_/\\\\/__\_///\\\//_\_\_//__\///__/\/_/\_/\___\//_/\/_\/__\_/_\///_\\/\//\/_/\//\/\///\/\__\__/\\_\__\/\_\//_/_/____//\_//_\\\_\/\\/_/\/\\_/\\\_//__\___\//\_\_\/\//\\/\_/\//_\_/\____///\//\/_/\/\_/_/\///___\_\_\//__\_\__\///\\\_\//_\\/_\\\__/\/\___\\/__//_\\_\_\/_\/__/_\_/_\///____\/\_/\\___\/_\_\_/\_/\\_\//\\\_/\/\/__/\/\__/\__/\//\_\\__/_\///_/__\__\\\/_\\_\___////__\____/\_///\/\_\/___\/\\/\/__\____\/__\__\_/\/////___\\/\\//__/\_\_/_\_\_\____\\/\__\\\/\___\\__\__//\\/\//_\/____\\_//_\_\\\\__//_\/\\/_/_/\_\\\____\\__\//_/\_/___\\\____\_\\\/\\//\_//_\_\\___\\//\/__///_\/_///\/_/_/_/_\____/_\_\___/_\\/\____/\\_/_\\/_/\//\_//___/_____/__/\_\_\_///___/\___\\_/\/\\___\__\/\\\\/\\///_/\\/\\\_\\__\_/\/_\_\\\\_///////\/_/\\\\/\/_//\/__/\_/////\_/\\_/\/_/\///\/\\_//\\_\_\/\\\__\\/_\\_\\\__\/_\_/_/\_/\_\_\\\/_\\\_\_\\___\__///___/\__/_///_\_\__/_\__//\_//\_\_\_\_\/_//_/\\\\////_/___\\_____\\___/\/\\_/___\\\/_\____/\__//////\\\/\_\\__\/_/_/\\\/\/\\_\\\/_//\///______\/_\_/__\\\_\\\____\///____\\\\/_/__//__\/\\/_/_\_\_\_\///_\\__/\\_\/_____/\//__\_///_/\\/_\\/\_/\_//\/\////_/\\\\/\/\\\_\/\_//\/\__/\__//_\/\_//\_\\\\\//\\_\\/\_\\/_//\//__/_\\\\\\_/\____\\\__\\_//\/\___/\/\__/____/\/_\/_/_\_/\__\/\/_\//\_\/_\_\\\__\\/_\///___\/\/\__/__////\__/_\//\\\_\/\//\\_\_/\\__\\///_///\\\_\//__\/\_/\///__\\__\_/_//_\_\___///__/\\\\\\_//__\\_//\___/\//_\\_\\/\\/_/\_\\/\/\\/_\\_\_\/\_/\//\__//////__\_\/_\/\\//_\\\\\\\/_\\\/_//\_/\\/\///_\_\_\\/\____/_/\_\\__/\//___/\//\__///_\/____/_//_\///__/_\/_\\_/__/\/__\\\__/_\_/_/\_\\\_/\_\___//_\/_/\__//////\//\_\\\_/__/_/\\/__\\__//\/_/_//_/\/\_\/_/\__/////_/\\\/\\_\_//\\_/___/\\///__\\/\__\/_\\/_\__\/__\_\/\\_/\__\/\___\\__\__//__\//\//_//_\//_\/_/\\_\\_\_/__//\\\//_/\__///\_\/\\////\\__/_/_///\_\/\_/\_//_\///_/____\\_/\/___\/_\\_\//_\_\//\_//__\_/_/__\_\/_/__\\///\\/\\/\/////_/_/_/_///////__//\__/__//\////\_/__\__\//\_\\//\\_/\__\\/\/\/_\\\\/\_\\\/\/___//\/___\__/\\_\\\\_\\_/\/\_\/\////_//_\_/\//\__//__\\\\\//\\\\\__\_\/\_\//\///\/\\_/_/\/_/___/__\___\/_/_/_\_/\_\//\/\____\\_/\\/_\/\__/_______\\_\//____\__//__/___\\//\\////\/\__\__\\___\\_/____\_/_\/\/_\\__////\\\\___/\\/\//_///_/\___/_////\//__/\__\_/_//\//_/\_\\__//\//_////_\_/\_///___//_\//_/\//__/\_/\\_///\\/\\_/_/_\/__/_\\\__\_/\//\\/_\___\_///_/\/____/_\____///\__//__///\_/\\___\_\_/\/\\/\//\_\/_\\/\\_\\/_//\/\_\__\//_\__//\/__/\/\___/\/_\\_/\_/\_\_/\__/_/\\__/_\__\__\_/\\\__\_/_/\\_\\/_//\_/_\/__\__\_\\__//_\\__/_/\/__///_/_\_/\\\__/_\_____\\/_\\\_\\\/_/_/\/___\\_//\_\_//__\\__/\_/////\___\__\/_/_\/_\/\/\\___//_/_\\__/\/\\///\/\___/__/__/\/__\\//_/_\_/_\/___/__//\\__\\\//\/\\\__/_/\/\\_/_\/\/__/\\/__//_/_/\/\///__//\_/\\\__/___\__\/\\/\_/_\\/_\_\/\\////_//\_\_//__\\/\_\\/\\_\/_\_\/__\\__\\\_/_\\/\/_\\\\//\_\_\\///\\/\/\_\\\\__\//_\/__/\/\___\___\\//\\__\__/\/_/\//__\/\/\\\////____///\_\_\\///\/__/_///_\\/__\__/\/__\\\\_\\_\/___\\_///\\_\_\\\\__\_\___///_\/_/\\\\__\\\_/\//\/_//\\\//\\//\/\__\//__\_/__\\\_/__\//__\//_\_/\/\_\/_\/\__/\_/_/_\/\/_\\\/\/_\/____\_\\__\\\\\_///\\\_/\_\//__\__\__//\/_/_/__\_\\\/\__/__\/_\__/\//\/\\\///_\//\/_/\\_____//\\/\\_____/\/_/_/__\\\__/\\_\//\_\_\_/\/\///_\__/\_//_\//_/\\\___\_\_\/_/_/_\_\//\///_\\\/\_\/\/\_/\_/\\/_//_/__//\/\/_\//_//_/_/_////__/_/__//\/\//_//\/_\\\\/\\__\\_\\___/_/__\\_\/__///\/\_/\/_\//__\/_\\/\__/__/_\/\///_/_\\_\_//___/\/_\_/\//_/\_\_\_\/_///_///\\_\//_/\\\/\\_/\/_\//_\__\_\___\_\\\\\/\\//_/\_/\//_\/_\_///_\/\\/___\\_\_\___\/\/\\////_\__/__\_\\/_/__\_\\\/\////\\___\/_\\\\\_/_/_\__\__//_/_\/_\\\__\__\/_\\\_\_\\/_///_/\/\/__///\\_//__\__/____\_//\/\\\\\_/\\/__\\__/\\\\_\/_\\_/_/_//\/\\///\//_/_\///_\/_/\\//\__///\\\_\/////_\\\/_///_/\\/\/_/_/\__\\/_/\_/\\\_\/\//_/\_/\_/\\\\/\/_/\\/////_/_\\\/\\/_\/\\__\_/__//\\_/_\_//_/_\_/\/_\\_\/\//\_/_\___/__\///////_\_/___\\/_\\\\\//_\\__\\/_/_//\__\_/\///_\///\\/_/\\___/\\\\\\///\\/\_\/\_\_/\\\/\//_/\\_///_/_/\_\/\//_//__//////__/\_/___\___/\\___\\/_/\//\\\\\\/\\_/\/\\/_////_\/___\/__\__/\\___\\_//\_\__\\__//\\\/\/___/\//\/\\\\//\//___//\\\///\/_\\_/\_\\\/\/_/__\\\_\_//\__/__\\___\/_///\\\/_/\//\//___/\/\__\\__\////\__/_/_\\_/\/\_/___/\_\\//_/_//\\\_\\\/\_\/\\//\_/__\\_/_\_\\\/_/__\/_\\\\\/__//\_/\//\//\/\/\///_\__\_\/_///__//\/\/_/\//_\\/\//_///___/_\_/\\/__/\\//__\_\__//_//_/_\\//__/_\_\_/_\/_/_//__/___\\\___\______/_/\//\_/_\\\__//\/_//\\\__/\/////_//\_\\/\_/__\/\/__/\\\\\/_\//_\\\__/_\\_\\/\__\\\/_/__/_\//__///\/\_/\_/_//\\_///\_\/_//\/_\\\\\\\\__\_/\///\/_\_\\\//_/\/\\\/__///\_/___\/\\_\/\/_/\/_///___\__/\/___/\///\///_/\\\/_/\_/\\/\_/\_///_/\\\\/_/__/\/\/_//\/\_//\//__\__/__//\\\/\__/\\\_\__/__/_\//_\\_\_\_\\/_\\/\_/\_/__\
```

**Valid:**

```
_\_/
Generator: +-

\\\_//
Generator: -

\/\_\_
Generator: --

_\\__/\/
Generator: +--

\\_\__\/\/
Generator: ---

\\\__\____\/
Generator: +-----

__\\_/\______/\\\_\/\/_///\\_\//\_\/_\_/__/___/__\\_\_//__\\_/___\_______//\/_//__\/\\\__\/__\__/_\/
Generator: ++++++++++++++++++++++-------------------------

_/\_//\_\\//___\\//\/\/_\\_\/\\/\_/__\_//\/\__\/\//\\/\/\\\/\\\_//_\/\_\\\/__/\__/\_/_\\__/___/\__\_////\___\/\\\_//\\_\__/\_/\//\/_\/__\//\\_//\\/\/_/\\/_/\_\/\_/__//__/\//_/\_\__\_\_/\////__///__/////_\/__/\\/\_\\/////_\//_/\\\/\//\\/\_\_////\\_\/\_\//_/_/_\\__\\\\\_//\\_/__//\_/\_\/\_//__//__\_\//\_///_/////__\\/\\/\//_______//_\//_/_/__/\/\/_\/__/\///_\_/\/////\/\__///__////_/\\\_\/\___\\\//\/\_\/\////\_/\___\\_\_/_\\__\\___/_\_///\____/\\\/\_/\/\\\\/_\/\/\\\/\\__///___/___\\_///\_/\///__/_/____\\/___\___\\/\__//_\/\\//\_//\_____/____/\/\_\/_\__/\\\/__/_/_/\__/_/_\\/_///__\\\\/_\//_/__\//\_\//_\/_\\_\/__/_\_\\_\\//_//_\_/_\/\\\\/__/\/___//__/_/\/_\/\//___\/_//\/___\__/\/_\//__\\_\///\\/_\_/_\\//\\_//\\\\\_///_\_/__/\_/_/_\\_\_/\/_//_\\/__\\/\\__//__\__\\\\_/\____\___\//\_\_//_/_/__//_\_/_///__/_/__\/\///\_\/_\_/_\\//\//\//\_/\\/\/\///\/\/\\_\//\__\\//__\_\_\\_\_//_\/_/__/__\_\\\_//\\/__\_\\_/\\_/\_////\/_\_\\__\/_\//_\_\/_/__\\//__\_\\\\/__/_\_\/_\\__///\/\_\/\_/\\_\\/\/_\\\//\/\//\_\/_/_/\//\\\/\\/\\_/__/_///__\\/\_\_//_//\//___/___\_/\/\__/\/_/\\\_\\/__\//\/__\_\//\__\/\__\//__\_/_\\_/____/\/_\/__\_\\_//_\\_\\__/_\/_/\\/\\__\\/__//_\/\/\_\/_/__/\/_\_////\\/_\_/\\\_///___\_/__/\/\__/\\_//_\_\_/\/\_\_/\\\/___//__///___\/_\\/_\\\\/__\//\__\\_\\//\/\____\/__///___//\__/_\__\__\\\\\/_\\\//\/\\//__/__\\//\\/\\\__\\\_\_//__/_/\__\_\_/\/\\\_\\//___\_/\/\___/_/\/_\\_\____/\///\/\\\\_/\/_\\_\//\/\/_/_\_//__\\\_\____\/\\_//\\\\\//_/_\_/\\_\/___\/__\_\_\\\\//__\\__\_/_/_\_\\__\_/\///__\/\/__/\__\_\\\/_//\_\//__\/\\/\\/__/\/\\\/____/_\__\\_/_\\\//__//_/_\\//\/\/\_/\_/\\_\//\__/\\/\\_\_/_/\_/_/_/\\_\_//__\/\__\\/_\////____/\_/\//\\//\_/\/_/////_\_\/\/\\////\/\\_/////_\___\\\\\/___\///__//\\__//_\\/\/_//\\__\\//\\/__\\/_\/_/_\_/\__//\__\\\\_/\/\__//_\//_\\___/_/_/___\/_/_\\\\__\_____///__//_//_//\///\//_//\\_\_\_/\/__/\\/\_\/\_///__//_//_\\///_/_/_/\\_\__\\/\____\__//////__\//_/_\\/__/\////\_/\__///\\/\//__\/__/_/_//\//_/\/__/\_/_//\\/\\___/_\\_/\/\_/_\__\__\/\/_/\__\///__////\__/\__/_\\_////////__\/_/____\/_\\\\/\__\\\_\///__\/////_\//\//_\__\/\\__\\_/\/\\//__\_/_\/\//\_\/\\/\\/\\_\\///\\\__//_\\_\//\__//_\/\_///\\/\/\_\//\/____\\____/_/\/_/\/__\\\_/__\\/_/_/\/\\___////__\\/////\___\\/_\_//_\\/_/\//_/\__\/___\__\/\//\/__\_\\\_\/_\//\/\//\/\\///\///\/\_\\//\_\\/\\\____\\\/__/////_\_\///_\\\\_\__\_____\\_///\//\_//\/\_\\_\\/\__/\\/\\_//_\//\\/\_\\_/__/_\/\\/\_///\/\\/\/__/\_\/\\_/\////___\\//\\_\/\//\//\___//\/_/_/_/__\//_/\\_\_\/_/__///\_\\_\\\\_/______\/\\__\/__/_\_/__\/\\___\_/__//\_\/_/_\\_//\/\_/\__/\\\_\\///\_/\\_/_\/\\/_\/_\\\/_\\\_/_\///\\/__//_\\\__/___\\_/\\_\__\\\//\_/_///\_//\/\/\_\\/\\/__\_____//\\_/\/\/\///\_\__\______\//_\\\\/_/\\/\\//_\\_/\\__/__\\\/\\\_/_/\__\_\//____\\\\//\\_/\\/\\\_\///_//\_//\\\/\__//////_/_\//\\\\__/___///_/_///\\_/_/\_\_\//\/__\__//\//\/\/\__\__\\/_\_\//\_//\\\///\\\/_\\____\\\/__\\_/\//\/\\\/\_//_/_\\\_\///__//\_/_/\__//___//_\//\/_\//\\///\__\__//\//\/\/\___///_//_\/\\_/_/_\//__//_\_\\//\/\_//_/_\/\/__/////\_/__\//\/_/\__/\_\\\/_\_/__\\_/_/\///_/\_/\/__/_/\/\/\\//\///\/\\/__\\_\\/_/_\_/\\//\_\\_\______\\_\_\////_\_/\\__/_/\\\\//_\/\_\\_/\_\__\_\\\\///_/__/\__\_\/\____\__/_//\/_\\/_//\/_//\/_/_\_//_/_///_\\\_//\_\_/__///_/\_/___\___/\_\_/\\//_\/_\/////\\_\//_//_/___\/\\/_//\__\__/___//\___/_\\\/\\_/_/_\\//\/_\\_//_//_/\__/_/_/\_\/_\\\/__\\___\___/_//\/_///\_/__/__\__\\\__/_//\\/_/_/__\\\\_\\_\/_\_\\/_/_/\/\\__\/_/__/\//__//_\_/\\\\_\/_\_//\__/\\_///_/\\\/\\/\_/\_\/\\\//\_/_\\_\\//\//\\//___///\\\//\__\_//_//\/_/\/\/__\\\//\/____/___/\__/\\_\_///\//__/_//_\\\\_////\__\//\_/_/_/\\_/_/\\___/\\\\_\_\///\_//_\_\\\/\/\_/__\//_\\/_////_\\_/\___\/___/__/_//_\\/_\/__/\\/__///\\/\/_\\__\///\//\\\\_\\_\/_\_\//\\/\\/\\//\_\\\__/\\\__/\_\\\_/_\\_/\\__/\\/__\\/\\\/__/\//_\/__\___\//___/_//\_//_///__/_/\\\_/_/\_/\_/__///_/_\_\_/\__/\\__/\//\__\/////_/_\\\\\/__\\\___\/___//__\\/\\_\\\\/_/__\_/\/_//\/\_/\\/\_\\/\\_\\\\/\_/_/\/_//_/__/\\\_///_/\/_\\///_\/\/__\\_//\\/\__//_\\__/_\//\\_\_\__\\/\/\/__/\/_\\\\__////_\/_//\\//_/\\/\__/_\/\__/\//_/\__//_\_\//\_//____\\\\_\/\/___\/\/\/___/__\///\/_\___//\_/\__\\_/___///\//_/__/___//_\/__\\\_\/_\\//\__/\____/_/\\/__\///_/\__\\/_/_/___\/_\__\/_\\/\/\_/\_\/\__\\\//\\\/\_\____/\/_\_/\\/__\\///_\_\\//__\_/__\//\___/\_\_//_/___\_/\\\/\\_\///\/_\\/_\_/_\/_\\\_\___\_\//_//\_\_\_\/_\\/\//_\\/\\__////\\__\___\/_/\_/\___/_\_\_\__/__\//\/_\\___\/\\_/\\_\\/_\\__/__\_/\_\__/\//____\//_____\__/\//_\////\//\//\\//__/__/\\\/_//__/\\\_\//\_/\\\\/___\__//_/\\/__\_/\__\/_\//__\_/___/__/_\///\/__/\_\\__/__\/\_\/\/_/\/\_//_\_\/\__\/_\\/////__/_\_/\_/\_/_\/\\_\\\//\_\\\/\_//\//_\__//\//\\\/_\/\/\/\_/_/_/___/\\/\_\\/\\_/\__\/\//////\_/\////\\__/__\\\_//\_///_//\/\_/\/_/\/__\_\__\//_/_/_\\\/\/_/\\__/\_\_\_\_//\\\//___\__/\___\_____\_/\\/__\\\\\_\/__/\\/\____/\//___/_//\/__////\\//_\/\_/\/\\\/_/__\\/\////_\/\/_\/\___/__/\___//\////\\\_\\\_/\////___/\\\\/\_/_//_/\_/\_/\\/\/_//____///___\/\_\_\\//_/\\\/\___\/_\/_/__\//__/____\/\_/_\_\/\//\\_//\///\_\_\_/\\//\_\\_/_/_\__\_\__\//\\/_\_/\_\/__\\//\\//\///\\/\_/_\_\\_///\///_/\//_/\\//\_\_//_/\/\/\\\\/\/\_\_/\//\_\///__\/\\_\___///_\_\//\_\\/\\/\_\\\/_\/__/__/\/_\\_\/\__/\\\_\_//\/_\\/\_///_\//_\\__/__\_//\\\___\__/___///\/\_\\_/\/\/\\\\/\///\_///////\_/\/\\\_//\//\_//\_//\\///_//\/\_\_\/____/\\_\___\_\\//\/\_///_\\/_//_\/_\\\_\_/_\\//\_////\_\_/\\/_//__\\//\_\/_\///\//_\_/\/\_/___\\//__//__\__/_//__/_/_\\_/_\_//\\_\\\/__///\//_/_//\\/_//__\_\\/\_\_\///__/_\/_\\_/\_\\\/\\\__//_///_/\_///__\/\/\_\_/_\/\_/\/\\\\_\\_//\_\\\///\\\/\__\___\_/\/\_\/\/_//_/_\/\\/\_\/_/_\/_/\\___\/_/_/\____//\\\_/\_/_\/\_/__\\\/\/\\\///_\\\\\\/_\__/\_////_/\/_\///\//_\/_/_/\\\___\\\_\//\_\\\_/____/___/_\_\/____\__//\__//\/_\/__\\/\_\___\\//__////__///__\\\_\_\__//_//\_/_\__\_\_/_//_/\\\\_////////__/\__\/\//\//\\\_/\_/_/\_\\///___\\_////_\_\\__/___\_/\_\\\_/_////_//////\\__\\/_\///__///__\_/_/__/_\\/\\\/\\/__/_\_\\\\/\_/___\\_\//_\_\\/\_\/_\///_\__/\_//\/___\__/\_\__\_/_/\\//\/_//_\\\//////\///_//_/_\_//_/_\\_\/\\_/_\\////_\_____\\/\/\_///_\/_/\//_\/\_\\_//\\__\\_/\/___\/__/\/\___/_\\_///\/\/_/\_/\\\_/___\__//_\__//\\/\__/\\_\/\\_/\_\_/_/_/_\\\////_/_/_//__//\\\_/\//\_/\_/\_\/\\___///__\\\__\\_//_/\__/_\_\\/\_/_/\\\///\\//\____\/\_\/\/_\///_\\//___/___\\_\\//\_\\/_\///___\\//\/\\_/\_\\//\\/\_\_/\\\__/_\_\_/\\\\_\\///_//////___\/\\/\/_\\/\\/\/\\\_\\_//\\_\__/__//\/\//\_/\/_//\/\/\/_//___\_\____\/_/\\/__/__/__\\\_\____\_\/_____\_/_/\\_\\__/\___/\_\////_/_\/\__\////_\\//_///_//\____/\_____\\\//\__//\\\/__//_/\\\__/_//_\/___///_\___///_/__//\_/_\/____\_//_\///_//\\/_\//\___\//\\_\/\_/__\_//\/_/_////\\/_///__/\/\__/_\/\/\//\_//_/_///////_//_\_/_\//\_/\\\_\_\/\\\//\\/__/_\/_/\_\\_/_/_\\////\/\_///\_/\/\\\___\\_\/\\\/_\//\/___/\/\_\_\__\_/\\/____/\/___\/_\_\\_\_/\\\\\\/_\/\\/__\\_//\\\//\\__\_\__/_\_\\\_\__\_/_//\_//__//\//___\/__/_____/\\\_/__/\/\/_//\__\///_\/\_\\\//_//_//\/\_\_/\\\__\/\__//\__\\_/__//_//_/_\\__/__\//\_\/\__/\\\_//\_//_/__\///_///\//\\__///\__\/\//__//\_\\//\_\_\_/\///__\\\\//_/\_\\_//\///\___/___/\/___\\_\\/__/\\\///\_//___/_//\\_\\_/_\//\_//_\___/____\/__/__/_\__\/\/_/\///_///___\_//\_\\\/\\//____//_//\\\/_/\/_\/_\\\/\\\__//\_\\/\\//\/_/\\_/__/\_\\//_/\\\__\/\//\\//\_/__\/__/\_\_/\\_\_//\//_/_\\_/_/___/_\_\\\\\_\_\///_\_/_/\__/_\/\_\_\_/_/_//_/_\_\/_\/_\_//\_//_\//\_\/\_/__/___\\\/\\/_/__\_///_/_///\\\/_///_/\_____\__//\\\_/_\\__/\\\__//_\/_\/_\/__\_\//_\___\/\/\\\__\//_/\\//_//_///\_\\\_///__\\/__\\_/_\/\\\\_/\\\/\\/\_\//_/\/_\/_\/////\\\\//__\_/___\/\_//_\/\_//_\///\\\\_\_\_\_\__\_/__/\/__\\//_\/\_/\_\/\__/\_////\/\/\_/\__/\\//\/_/_/\_/__\_/\/\/\_/_/\_/\\\\_\/////___/_\//_/\/_/\______\_\/___/\\\/\/\/_____/__\_//_\\\\_\//_//_\_\\\_/\/\__//\_/\__/////\__/_/_\/\/\\/_/\_\_\\\/\/\\\\/____\/\\\/__\___/_\\//_///_/_/_\/\\\\\_/\_/\\_/\/\\/___/\___\_\/_\/__\/\///_/_\\_//\_///_\_//__/__\\\\_\__\__//\\/_\//\\\//__\/\____/_\//_/_\\/\\\\\_/\_\//\__/\\_/_\/\\_//\\__/__/___/\/\/___/\\/\/\_/\_\\\_//\_\/__\/\//___/_\/____/\_\_/\\/\/\/\__\_//_/_\//\__\\\//\\/\_\/_\////_////\_/_/__\\\\_\//_\\___\_/\///_/_\\\//\__\\_\_/\/_/_\///_/__\//__\/\\___/\\\\_//_\/_\\\\\_\/_\\//\_\\//___//\\_\_/\/_/\/\/\/__\\\\__/\/_//_////\_//_\___/\/\///\/__//_\\_//_///\\_\/_\\\/\/\\\/_/\_\///___/\\\\\/__\/_\/\__\____//\_\_/_\_\\_/__\\\/\_/\////__\_\/_/_/\__\_\__\/\\\/\\//__\\__\/\/\\__\\\_/\\_\/\___/__\\/\\___\////\\_____\\_/\/_\\//___//_\\\//\_\/_\/\______//__/_\_//__/__//___/\/_\_//\//_/_\//_/\//__\/__///\_\\___/_///\_/\///__/_//\/\_//////_/\\_\\_\/\//\\___\\_///\_\_\/__\_/\/\_/__\___\\/__/\_/\_\__\//\\_\\\/_/__\/_///\//____/_\___\///_//\///_/_/\/\\/\_____\__\\//////\\///__\_//\/_//\/\\////_/_____\\_/\///\\__\/\\_//\//_\//__\/_\____\___/__\/\/___/__\_\\__/\/\__\_\__///_\//\_/__///\/\_/\_/\///_/_/_\___/___/_\_/\_/\//\/\\/_//_\__/\\\_/_/__/\///\//\_\/\\/\_\\/\//_\/\\_/\\\\/\_//__/\/_\/\/_//\\//\//_\_\/\/_/_\//\//\__////\\_\\\_///////_/\/____\\\\/_\\/___/\\\//\\/_//__\//_/__\__\___\/\_/\/\//\__/_\__\_\\//\\_\__//\_/\_\\__\/_\\_\/_\/_/__/___\\//_\_\//_\//\\/\/_//\/\\/__\\\/\///_\_\\_////_/\\__/_\\__/__/_\////\//\___/\\/_\__\_\/_\_\\////_////\/_\_//\_\_\/\_/_/_//\_/\/__\/__\/_//_//\\\\__\//\_/\_\\\\//\\\\_\\\____\\/\_\_/\////\_///\___/___\\\\_\\\//\\\\\\/\_\_\_\/_/_//\\/\___\_____\___\/__\/\\__/\/_\\/__\_/\_\__/_/_/_\/\\____\__/\/_/___\/\____\//_\////\_/__/\_\//\//\_/_//\\/\__\_////_\/_/_\/\/__\__\\///\\\\_\\_\/__\\///_/__/_\\/\\\/\\/\_\_/_\\////\_/\_\/\//_/\/_/\\\\///\_/\\__/_\/\/_\/\_//_//\__\___/\_\/___\/___/_/__\//\_\_\__\\/\/_\_//_\_\\_/___//\//\/\\/\_\/\/_/\_\/__\_\/_\__\/\_\///_/_\\\\/\____/\/\_/_\_//\/\/\//_//\\_\\/_\/\_\\__////\_/__/\/\////_//___\/_\\/_/_\_//\_/\\___\///_\/\\_///__/_\/___////_\__\_\__\\/__\___/_/\\\\\\//\\\/\_\/___//_\\_//_/_/\/\_//_/\\\/_/_\_\/\__/\_/_\/\/\_/_/\/__/\_/\\/_\_/\_/\//___\_____/\/_/\/\_\/\_____\\/___/\\__//\_____\\/\_\//\//__\/_\___\\/\_/_/\/\///\__//__\__/\\__/_\_\/_/_//__\////__\_/_\/_\___/_\/\__/_\\_\\//\/\\/___\___/_/\\\\//\___\\\_/_\_\_/_/\_/\/\___\//__\\\\_/_\////\_/_\/__\\/////_\_\_////_\\///__/\/_\__/\___\//_/_/__//_/\\//_//__\/\__/_\///_/__//\_
Generator: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The generator output is just an example. It needn't be "ordered" as the one seen above (although I assume this to be more practical to implement).

That last test case may or may not be 10000 chars long and my computer may or may not be trying to find a valid parcours of length 500000 at the moment.

Comment: My code was failing with following input: `\\\_//`, so you can add it as testcase if you want to. Also is it legal to have speed 0 in middle of track?

Comment: Can we write a single program outputting both the validity and the acceleration, or one that outputs something other than a string of `+-` for incorrect cases? Also, can we assume an _ exists?

Comment: @Jiří Added. As for the speed, 0 is allowed.

Comment: @emanresuA Single program: Sure, why not. Different output from `+-` for incorrect cases: As long as your falsy output is distinguishable from the truthy output/acceleration string, yes. Assuming at least one flat piece: No.

Comment: @mindoverflow In the comment you state speed `0` is allowed for the flat part, but in the challenge description rules you state "_On the flat bits the driver must either speed up or slow down manually, again, by 1 m/s. They mustn't do nothing._" So which of the two is it?..

Comment: Also, it makes sense it isn't possible to be at a negative speed, but you may want to explicitly mention that in the rules. ``/_/\`` was truthy in my program with output `+`, because `-1 + 1 + -1 + 1 = 0`, but the leading `-1` would make the speed go from 0 to -1 m/s, which isn't possible (and which I assume is the reason it's falsey)? Or am I missing something, and ``/_/\`` is falsey for another reason?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I added the rule you suggested in the second comment. It should also answer the question in the first comment, which I think may be a misunderstanding. It's allowed to _have_ a speed of 0 _before and after_ the flat bit, but it's not allowed to _change_ your speed by 0 _on_ the flat bit.

Comment: @mindoverflow Thanks, that makes sense. And in that case I assumed the correct things when I posted my 05AB1E answer, so I won't have to change it. Great challenge btw. :)

Comment: This sentence seems to be the wrong way around: "The up-/downhills accelerate/decelerate the bike by 1 m/s."

Comment: @m90 oops... Fixed it

Comment: These bikers aren't very skilled if they can't even accomplish `_` or `___`.

Answer (score 5):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) `-E` - Validator, <s>82</s> <s>61</s> <s>59</s> <s>55</s> 48 bytes

```
:a
s/D(_*)U/\1/
ta
s/_U|D_//
ta
s/__//g
/./cF
cT
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZw9rm3rUUXz0wxHgGQKMov4QYREwosoq4TMTwNsB0j0hAQJQUCPoDWcvWqMWesag9-957y91_q-qllzjpIQ__Yfv_3Hf_ivv_vFL__yF7_-73-p7q766ef6z9__7p9--av_-bO_-Puv39ZPfzR_8sc_V_95ff3u8_P8_K8_TfnD99_--av-tH7zV1-_-dv93r_zx__-zV_XVH91zfdzv6rn--nTX99_fP_l88uv5_vf__75_ec3n8_M57c9z4-fX_R-8_PD59fPF6bn-eh-43nM9y--v_b9j883Py_-_kXtE57_-fzj--X7sn3e50mfZ87na5_nls_0Uf2cpJ5jzOezvQ_4nOB5DJ96DlfPmTkT367nM89tPnceX_x8ezji54s8tnpP8dzgubyP_bzz-c9TL0_xPDOvyduf2_NsjrN_e8rE9dpKbbXqedDzSqrxPId3bh3KZ35qth9rzzmpzv7u-Vezjdgu7GGfb241thxFaX3z85A9fu1Re8s9W6feTq0c9g6jDoZ61YroEcPznf3LvqTpSK-U9ua9bY6y9gxPA57_PDfcquw9n6Nt4YbuPM99pMjVn7LR4N7H7RHqTjjbKi9a9isSe-RA2Xss8JaMB0XiTzf3p-e4e6K9ZqvsWsHOIFfVsrfa_91mzPZj1fwU3vdwp9lrbKU5GMrmgU_tOGck2nuKffTzkW2c_dgSjmXYKd6T1XZ7ogMaWc7XrDD53PNUjvto_2ngqYiLVcdYtrUr633InoHKr6IRwg7gFgr5bp2L4pSGUmnxM5w-vl5SQcVUr0d3xJ98xI5-M5B17vW8jqHj662FZUK3NlvdWlvTTZ-aMeJrqCpmqBLe4yhuCZFlMySP4rGZHTa_O1EylywqMJmpSnv2LqihhwxYp7TLcfEeiqfH0OBnaBju6lykrvBdZzA-iiu9zsVfdww0et6U-XFq-HmPUB1VDcZLlNhQVLud3h_aOtrljaC1NmSsd63o0sEhQpVcl3k4GFy8gAeZKGMtC_NL_lD-VjxmY_2QvZarFQCD559mnqHbhvNmaRGbFV3rDPfecQC0rfOBjdttwh7Zy2kafBhZrynn_cchZ81UWxfSe8iY9s_C1V_xQYA2miwkt6ky6SvCtK_hgDHBK74WK6A7OERf5nrRSJv3R9m4VXNxLWDMTi6D0abs44Tt202TnQDbK5rtUJoBzK_so21gbEDElLBUyKO1ypIB-XJrcILXntCMKJQlGjCT-4sVkpOz3liHfZqejeLdWtwWzCEqPmkEqZgY52rV5NT6ViR3dfOSKXA8bJbjdRMuGkDIW2D9q4cqBuBoLu3a6DJcMbVwzjYGNRAy8wpqr6RiMbTS8uowbwW6_57xHGMQXh4NQs8Ce6GbslIDOiD3lShT0knisczOQcPh0yNlGlh2UR027-Beh4XlZlCZdn3VdaCN64a518jA8Q6Y6Xm0gjhLag6MEvbg1Y2Qw60nE8wxEtZLQfmKbR4BU9y8YHVPXFRr-0JZFidVaipDtJNGar806IQNkoryWNgI9BtN2WU6vD3nk_R-4sqsDBgOnga14lbU4AZATgYg1cR2uPDq_PCHZFk2d9z00pWkZZa-dmGpZJHJU22fFZniCuBo84QMha3w_q0KTkrJ3qLqEh2P1V_z88SJxbfSktBF0eBF0OBdmy_9Sn7qPrxGTGTh2YjLurPUNaxDZKJwSKaEG_cMu1c1vObWkfxL8nVnrl5PYS9gWvlgObXh8Dnhg9fAgVXeCS-PO0ZfdikovsAzpjUrkhQNtnY5AH0slMCHAkWLEd468Te-jh5OO2QormWSoYDlumncsxbsw9lRwLp5sTY4bDZOMoyK89aYKRJkVB2v1iqEPolIg26Xm-iDPBlQXlx9demqQVyVI1XpC9sZWFhqs-Qvoa7uy1L1a6VgsldHgFj7HrCindOW8OeH3-yFBf2-keiA0MKCRCrEynmdg8T_Kvi3487auJNeUYroz0nNP00ear2QLZbEcmd0opOu-BBNxc9bZOgYCfA3sgwqWx0luOi00ct_IxfGfJMQA-Z6jcW7jbSJ1lZmso2BVui79es58GEXNDkluHYioKD0vMtcagdL9AApWv3nv5pFC5vYXzt_nLZVzx2iUY3q9g-boJyJm5qktM7jviN5SHgOKCXeHh_75O3mZuZwsPSSOfSU0n4n3N-yuWh9s2lKiW-MqYaH-Y7I3QEZFiRDxPzkGOBCq2VsUT_H2CUJKVukdMsXmlvZ1N3JNaJl7gkVvbvo4yqpFrPbQBjmVxf3eoMx21bceAKiNqeQ4m0XLTxpP8Vb9lqgg8SHh15QDWNuIO4cD-MasOe3mK4dy46xdy_sp_RtsUjvlWv04Ei3xInxSuE2rlGyCIDX9fK4FmHg7DPwYqCDs5ZaNAlC97H-vmHGVulQsjx1EHoNnZzXHaKNS6MOQS4YblCXuWPVVf-olfGpwXxu-3KWPg4MT7aJ0tdVtSyhFJBXkZBbAtoeKUOSLkxx9c98X40ZYpxGMO9kfeOO7cqTZdrcNWICitYkwKm5j0CHO9D6OXcj4EfQDnl0rCT8hh3GIS4iXjkWKROfHY9in0m4acFAVKbep6ahLhnllmHuxMDhMoFM5qBLBpFUR4hv2Slt4AO60tuYd9lIIFRq5jpbLFE6zjd2-_7OCIuMEkRKEaF8VA1wk-_zB4YFLXgPgjk4aTbxZrE99J9fDlblpInhnORHHKfLI3pCfGHj0tfkhqmoq_GU7DCHI4MGhMlxhxnRV1jImoA-b8WQGm6GgALC9CwM7J1JdE7GpR2oOU5ysKDOcsljeRiZ5mK89WTYkCEUTlr6CdUU6F1Oe-aJHiqr_QzhWqUoa_I94dK7mtTx_9I09asygwAFbmYAANb2uFFo8LpLeBD1Ag3c2kzA-h2v4ykhOI8ckWm8OqCQHK181UUjgWNUl0kePut3uKFDKfhWOO29sravgmMPvh7C3GHbNMLhg_S0HnMQRjuj4aeT22Xw38T-cAP8UjfXe-UFR4gMRgglyog4Ql3Uy4ipI5IKlsIreF4lv2mRprnmk6pDCk7hHP-E2kcqrc5iUBzzsrn8hZNuHmw3b7xcPkbZGD-liZeiikeH2dYOigvl_iM3r8gcLIO2PGRQN9NSDETfiGaaYjntatRamty8-TEgxOD0eut6uHyxtwH61qUwlLEn5WpTFnNy68JLhwh-rW7xH7ms7Owry3xoGi3ImECidbtLqRI-XpE6bRjwyyQgt4ZbtuzcDmwMzr9qJZXFY7MGyWLM22atXqxjunqyEjbG7Aa3aW-2bjlsYyjQjQGOn6OqSZf5WCc8KdvQybjLFg_bI5gbpyTKzFzZuIzCkfnWSkZswx4QN7SGZWxsis9lrMBEgkcQzTWI3cU7lw9tE4T8gi8M9pdRG3UhAIcR3AnaXLhYRVA-zKFk2Ap4VAWXcUQ-XiEL1hSMngZblBZi2CpVqtXW19m4zwgyQI40JBwIGEONvCjGyclvFwGzp14Iop3DvijjaJSgUWfEyOD1dp85JlbFae-IdcRKKI4oeS6k6ZdtGmG0LJGCKZS8blqBPVuPMfXNkMhKkBTBHBahx8FObG6lcdfAfX7Y1ub5v8ab-trY-NoZ-JIHvhrS6f3EFvz7B2iR8neupFN2dk2x84UkdZ2zV1uXvhF5XpIdsUKdZwU2042Q7Y2K731GtF7ARCKj3teeC0duNhQ-uDHYrB1NENZkiSu8al6ZYRaiev1iVDhI8cpHT-1Zgu8OaDK99ca8nddnWWELWWpqJn9eyHzKgYmySsh9OXO6Osd5biC0ns2r5X_irtVEYYEd3FyPd_SDTSMfElNuQAZ2nQ2huRo9TYBpME3mThrOjTm9FAoFhWWn7qxW46kdy5LELaqzn9ntkjxcN0rQdDNLUslwaGVClpaHlSojtgKVieEg1iXLtq3J3LV2rIVgLZ0BnTNch1PTW_taxUOWrK119rYJUCXc3fPshVChfzb7VagdmJMOG-9qpT4RMzc3zGbkYhCeRQp2nVzxB7bGeiZzPZgEK5eUIzwgPM8nIF6H7arYou9udyR3xSk-SHVlpWyHDjegguuuK59ecLUjH1FaZcvoSDaO1Er8Sqeml0kNH3THeJAzMe82Ak7YgTR3oaiqnYqRX18peTks9Y6zib0zgFSPGpDyeJ9Cvy2CatLH3iKsvBJBImpn3cPvGRd9tF-gzo1Bm6DPtICDUZnLna74LqpERy2z_la3wWgwI1WwkQaMxATzas9swBAFfLjZcywAnsomQVxYSXnJcyZFYq5EXVws2-EbJt1LGgUmVJocHmvJ6_F9NzqE5tmISxcuN74MAI5d4iqt75IBo2VHOldrHYMIYyTWRBrsxZz2mlpSwAFTCP9z5UkNdCSWLE0vO1aJBeuMe45QIzIs1BA9EJ2EYhlhJ32Kxr-CAtvLAzOgxDGLodVJDxnNmFFIeGL5at01HSIDyl9kt1Pc4mtgtZGeEUxK7z_m1rc5ZB_DqcWUjQ0ebk3rxgjlGJdBUfaAZECVj2bPWrvXrwrRGPL8-3bZOA5nAdluhD7ZtMpnRoksMJx-tCoZr9U1hoFSWmKFu7CPsyfJqIKDrUCK97xfC00ijluE5lKKS0WnLV-VsN2S0HDL5Ur8gzZ0hoB7dKyyFdco-caz05giZZS5EN76XvoV03NrK5ePC7glDthHvZIgKxQDHYKsMDsrK9k1qakJTmxZTerfWnoHXpX8MDM5sSUOHo4GzGjuDA189nKt4EvAsXWjMS1H5scj1hcYqLAJjjtIsNihOGDrm3pqsWeZvRxhdDNM1LEdp6HZIGy4RIVnl9O6QT2CcgOHQWpT8bIMcOUu74JVomNVpyshZAOufWJLJoUYxHQ7tnUpVQqJnKgI7vGhlqIc3jaFvFl2BHxqskC0mP_-QJtmtD9NlgrsFzFuUupVE14odyEMrFgWVg5-eQTyWE1cS6_kleMzaeWSNT4l5Y2CKcdoLAg3ACeoMI8a6S4g1QL3CVuVslu4FFxr43RjhNWNf2UDafcpLWVjKqCsM2wtPUXRJXYJlYM-WJ1wjxiF0I1DmktYXhlI-0d-Bbve6KKE2g2hBaMKzy44EpmwzNVBkKjQg8dsgS_TWil8MQedEVClzBp5XRdDO77Oe2Elp_CSruRVaym5gcHOhlC3aihcmCMz5TuRxXoxygvgijhQoLpP8bFBN0RIE5tgditzR8zyjvICmI04VjfJ8Q93jKwFW_1xGFsz7CCbgL10vnDXLhKTTAMVIXicmcEYJyOJncdp7QHgrgzKZrywPWK6W97IGujQ_OnYt8ajuxAlzNLUa3takYLQB1phgzsK6oh22moonO4Tz17dFJsfEMgUuqHXmorSlsNGVZyerapoYTZLKDMyMle6jQD13nOnPSVTZiIKrSYRJ54046VQ2shQqiKw_aa7bo1YbDKu4Q0Z-8Y89Ay67gCtLVOmqXdVysDMGmgASxTpSANXwOxYiSso_-RRuhvCXeHjdx1FCI3xTS5TrCjZvhB_0oBj7pVEQ0DkDjIkGgDRLkqZ9CVdEyiSScHi08CuEydX8eqSSbMOSPMtRG8sn5TL0FAN7WYBg7gcZOZNrQ4ix8SdV3NrNHKOuD_V6aX0NxfGNE5QbitFP5DqZvNlEDLDlF0qql-tcITbrrb-1L5EAu1rp3iP-SDq1GqlsGUxdArUIVE4qFSauGI7adO7CHrjoceadTARw0fQIwwZqySZea6xgJICV3HkqcwU2IDFUF2IkHkG-I06OPcwUCsdK1csHkcbcxtGa1uvAAJcet4WPYqYc21ClqRKVecEu3y_nYQoXsjb0ld0dRMFtrKyGEUz0bptpRtjapX70MkJtg7YZjAP8V7plsrZBdJ6K7G2NFj1pbezAn2_0h3T7JuEyejMgQult3F-LyE8vHt0FlwvOSOQqDs8-RVCxrvQJUFGoC2nwtwCdzI_oZgceG2JjI2bSAynTIwmTFF45FwMjZzGWJQXqcpoxa3mtSCWDy-Jv91xWtw8ZZgTMMFY942gDgHVlZAsee0jI2bnNmUlMgw0_YWiqmwYrv3lxcdkvAPesUENsHIyaqJtFSnPmOgkfHnKCauMQ7ECbc8wDmzgmKFlV3YSsrPsEqWTjYeHBN5tDLqdjBjJiAVTtZfrUW68dVTfvQ2bTf8mG4jGlK2ljg-q7zw8GPNuP7vohd3XbasHA1jv1J2-XBPnbuq3hzTCUlgKjFngh2l979eGaN0j7HGv9ltVv2wDwl6nI7qJjxcKGmqeYIsy4c4pIRXbhI9YjfqQs_Gm2JBesujQUgiybIkVQJtATq6b1dQ9bX87L8mUrvpypgKgRlTfjlRCDLA32NZZmlTjNKAVY9VZEsDakZGSydqWWYFcJwFC0wtnwcgCii2XBlhkjSsNSVnmigISXAiyLkcfcSRetdzKSlYn1Iub3YoWBt1wEoxYWrlEsinKrFiVyb29A2NYuDpTICJZwuMU_GZ54Zzt9i0maHT5kXeyVHRw0LnfWmlGyRwOhd-86u_OVMpfqRw2YATwWbFStdhzJmHqmXfQDfM2TnAbVlpVmyk7JCFkhz1s4adKziKFeFVjxCqlYz1liVX0Gbppu9VyCimVQup08l5ErdpAOa1zzDEU_98eht34AoYS2wsxdSDX9C0tC2snD4_tOAKdiKHtKCXvtcQ0cVqLLLdDgVfb4YTVLjdM3pWoVAJEvIWZXCX0CpLchqCexJS9Ey2uNo7eLs_h2M3gLpBjjik0sX6NeyRiysR5M4TjouNeHLNtf1dJn3XonjRMPeL8wzoiUZSz5WboidL8fQmJJBsVJWQKXvKMzIovPH9pV6U92ugn5Z5WnrEd8QH39_-r3v8B)

**Explanation:**

First following transformation is applied on the input: `\___/ -> ___`. This is done repeatedly, till the whole terrain is of following shape: `_/_/___\_\_` - rising from start and then falling till end.

Then following substrings are removed: `_/` and `\_`. Now the terrain is of flat shape `____` and it is just checked if the number of `_` is even.

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) `-E` - Generator, <s>115</s> <s>107</s> <s>78</s> 72 bytes

```
:a
s/D(_*)U/\1/
ta
s/D([^_]*)_/\1M/
s/_([^_]*)U/P\1/
ta
s/_/P/
s/_/M/
ta
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZrNqi5XEYbn5zIy0URC4UwcR3By4EzOKBULQb2BxEGuJRNBFPWO9Gr8vvU-T60WQZO9e3evrq56_wry01-__-Mf_v7tF1__5ovv_vVjdXfVN5_rb3_-4U9f_-rfv_317z98X9_8fL768nP1L-vDD_n929_Nd199Oa9LH-t1YbjwuT7tTVOfzp_q4_tCzvvHj_XpY_3ia47_y39-9s_pqQ-vt069_lX9-vXDvH57Hf2-_Pp1Oj--f5p5__ph3nfU-e194_u21z2vE-r8-D6l3ufO-3_v_5-DKj-8L_Ho69J57LzjvKDO3-q8pN6PvB7sOo-8z33fnre9Sz03n6sp8lw9Hcz3zPmefh9a54um8mmTC-976nyGT-SD3zeet6Wec5nD31_7_sfw_jpnVy69T8yj5zL_qByTkru9co7aqq0lB5-_Umz3lnbO6307r6fj71Nz9nT6c9qWLu-JQw8pu7bedHFr3qmezqf16TEVOFNqPGM-RbSYSBf79P_OhXcEBTyQSlLfqR6ENDVl3sBheHgoKQPLkKcy6FNWDc1IAed0sHkacL4vZTcoSz_Gqt-vGGY8xWec4irIDVg5PgeecdKYBU4mKCXa2Z4vPy9tp-ZIJ8-EcGPhs1PMWbdtGc3yLhOrNC2syIiXoNCq-fp0GcYe0gTx-WUqxQQnuTR8dvPcnucsmiZPLXrOOQ2L4XNxQJgQ5CIdC2a-nO6n7wC2hapUvYwYhCEyofTM8noQiUYUYHcAXQLP-vIcLA1vmOo41xSUQ62wBeesJqQvZacchwoXjV2eBNC9oHj0rot5ISLIBVJbaJw0XCGlUjHdA2Uzp-AOekQtasW7tYAL7OLv0MnWDn8LVIJ4fw7dz9HWGLo208rX0NN0jx5kkI32CfRAay64mWOnCYHXWhDoH3T66j10UUcb2UIdey_vIM7wosoIFT4Ihkpij11sJmqb1bdSQyOCuf16rsK8NIjn5KNSswaDFXDzqf7RADQ1wqVd2ElAUNa5LrLiitWtiskX6BVTBKuh5m0Rg_Heuq9H92GEILY27DJaM_JzlgAodtCzAtKRYsciLsoGtdSOjqf9UCIiEr1oxSmfqSRtcEAUch9BYLSGrqtI4ceKXnDVamOTdDp1oKELwwINiwesE1MsLexCn6bxpwgyqYm3M8XcLRcwrV73MKNpMwIJTSxfrbruhPCA8sJsfgHcFE7NTiwCmlqBRDELzTXt7pshRHbaQaZAFlQSaQRytMuNol0KMhgqjw4KSIjqVQEaTZ6_h22FONYlGdPY9BlSkuqqZ5EYgbD6UarMeC2uEQyQ0iZWchfyceXJZFQbB1uAFO95vpY0CTiGgBMw4lJ81OK0zVdl2G6T0PCVyZXoB2PoJQHf0SuVLbhGyDeavYMpXEaYG8Jb3dt5regFz22Eq4fBJXGQfcQrDhKgaOgkyNrMHmUG_TXbUx0c27Kb9L-V9N7wKuQHzmzFtnjj4SjAUDMcGvLZQ7U2vmxwbNVodMsx86MR0QUItdkExR0gWOxQFNjqpppa7Fl6LyWMaoaIStuRDc0G4cBNVGh2ydYY9RiUm3C4kVpXvF5GcOVbng2rtY6gTlUCyBpce2KbTAowGNOdWPpSopQkckGFcY-H2oqSvK0L-WW7I6BTswtEG_OfN7Ruxvh3yKYC54WN65Rq1WxeKHchBKxYFgIHHx4D-UrNqpZaySvHMxllkjU6ZcobAVPSaGwIX0CcoMMcNaa7DVJt4L7AFqXsFi4Fd7SrdKOF1aV_7QbS7lNKSmxqg7LKkF5aRTEldgmRAz5YnVCPFQpDNwqpLyF5pSHlX3uJ7HqpCxIqG0IbjGrzbIIjlkmWuX0wSNSmB8tsA9-ytbbxBQ96KSBK4Rp-XdeGQl_5XkjJRXiZrsyr9tLkRgyWG4a6oKFQYUqG5WFksV6M8CJwLThAoLjf5iODbogkTWQC7tbyDpvlHeUHIDbGsbpMXv1wx9i1IN0fydiKYW9kM2AnnSfctYvErKcRFUnwKDPEGJmxjr3HKe0bgLuWKPF4w_YY093yxqwBDvWfXvlWeFQXrAQuTT22p4CUCH2D1maDWwroWOy03RA43Rc8-XRdbP4nAulCl_RKU9Hakmx0Rfakq0YLvdmEMmNG5pPuRgB677nTVgnLdERDq05ExbPDeCCUMUJKUURsv-yuu0YkNmnX5A0z9qX5pmeiawgUWaZNU8-ulIa5a6AGbKLYiTThijA7duI2lH9ylOoGcAN89K4XEYbG1U0-plhRdvsC_OsGlJlPMhoSRG4hg6MRINpFaZmepKsDLWS2YavThF0ZZ67i1WUm3XXANN-G6NjyhXJpGqKh3SzIIC4Hy3ldqzcir4jLV31rFHJKzG918VLqmwvjDs6g3HaKeQDVePP1IGCGKLtUVD9GIYXbqbb61L7EBNp3nMZ7xAdQb68ChbRF0ymiDo5CoabStSu2k9a9C6PXHnrsWW9MRPAB9BiGtFWcTD9XWIiSBq6i5KnlFLEBiaG7JEL4TODX6si5NwYqpWPnisXjpo25G0YrWw8DIrj0PCV6BDF1xSHLpEpX5wI2-T6TJFE8Im-bvhZXl1HEVlYWrWhmse5YmcboWuU-dOFEtt5gu8S8Ee_hbts5p4BbpxORpUGqr3vLFdL3w90Rzb5MmKXO3OBC6x2cz60JD-8elQXVW58xkIg7NPlhQtq7ocsEuQBtcyqZ28C9nr-muD7w2BKhjZvICk7pGI2ZgvCFc0Eacxq0KD-kaqm1ajWPBbE8vEz87Y7Txs2LDH2CTDD2PRbUm4DqthAveewjY8zeryk7sWRg6I8oKsoGcuXitY9Zem_wXhlUAGsroyfKVuHy0EQl4eEpGVZLh2IFyswQDmTgZoY2u7KT4J3llGid2Xg4ZMO7gwG3sxTDGZFguvZQPdqNto7ou29DZnd-sxuIwrRbS918UH3r4WDEu7030Qu5r7ut3jCA9E7d6ss1ce6X-vTgRkgKS4E2S_iBrc_9WhOte4Qz7mC_RfVDNkjYUTqsG_t4REFNzQrSlNncOWVIRTbJR6xGfSNno00rQ2pJokObQoBlm1gJaLMhZz93V1P3tFydB2RKVX0oUxGgxqieidSaGMFeY4uyNK5GNUQraNW7JBBrx4y0nqxs6RXAddZAGHqhLAjZBsU2l25gMWvc1uCUpa8IIIMLRtYl9QHH2quSW7uS1QXqtZtsRQmDbjhrjEhauUSyKZpZkSqdO7MjxrBw9bLAiGQLb05Bb5IXrrLdfQsGjSo_5p1dKnrjoLxPrxSj9RyKQm8e_XdnKuEvVG5sQAjIZ8VK1caeKxK6nn5HuoFvI4Nbs1KqWk8JSTYhS_bNFt5V5ixciFc1QixSeqWnbLGIvoKu26ZbspBWCaTeSd4X0avWUC7WKXM0xf_bw5AbXwApkb1NTL0hV_ctJQtpxw9vtqMEJrGCFiqt3yuJO8RpJbLcDg28yg4VVrvcwLzbohIJJOI0ZvZTNr0SSe6GIJ6MKfkmRlytHT1VnuLYzchdRI65mUIR6wfdFyK6zCrvknBcdNyLV2zba7XuE4Xu2YGJR5R_WEdMFCW33AytaIefl-BIZqOihbDgAc-FWfHA-aFdlVLaqCflnlbW2FJ8iPv5T_b-Cw)

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3.8 - Validator, <s>92</s> 88 bytes

```python
lambda c,d={1}:1in[d:={g+1-a*2for g in d if g for a in(f in'/_',f in'/')}for f in c][-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVDRisJADHzfr9i3tndKWH05Cv0SI6Haqy7oWkpVRPz2msmeXGm3M0lmJuzwmI6XtP4ZxvnW8Hxqz7uu9ftF1zzDqw4xbbq6eR6@w7L9WvWX0R98TL7zsVcE3iovez0KkmKRQVG90ALx@@1mGbbz/RhPvz7UzuszjDFN5a2MabhOZVVVs7CQY2L9O2EWIVYOKpwhkAioE0yQMQxiTGeEiAzChWAoePGZEWWA0p9USyazDAsg6xFCtMEOPsBmK@wsCIgd/ctB8haWiQxmK3BWgqBsAsEy/FGYjYViAYsWuwbKDpLvQKff)

## Python 3.8 - Generator, <s>115</s> 113 bytes

```python
lambda c,d={1:''}:[d:={g+1-a*2:d[g]+(f=='_')*'+-'[a]for g in d if g for a in(f in'/_',f in'/')}for f in c][-1][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3RrsIgDIbv9xTcAc6l4ZybExKeBEiD4iaJZy7L1Bjjs8@WSaD8X/u3nZ7L@Tr@/k3zendhvaT/Q07iuM/uZayUb@uzda@hNV3a/djsh9iq3jmJUu9k20mfYn@dxSDKKLIoPSnmRKx6ChJQ7jch9ZtLDOIYfWeiN3F9nMvlJIxtBJ1pLuOi7qqM021RWusVA0ITINDfYAiIEIgZMWySFSJjg@yASmxkG3kQAKrkKcADkS@/Ogg2walvK6VqW91RF0CtUTN8AA)

Thanks to Kevin Cruijssen, Steffan, and xnor for -6 bytes.

Comment: -2 bytes in both the Validator and Generator by removing `>0` from `if g>0`; and another -1 in the Validator by removing the space at `a*2for`. :)

Comment: You also don't need the space at `1 in`.

Comment: You can also cut the spaces in `2 for` and `0 for`

Answer (score 3):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 107 bytes (generator and validator)

```cpp
g(char*x,int s=0){return*x?*x-47&&g(x+1,s+1)&&(*x=*x-95?32:43)||*x-92&&s&&g(x+1,s-1)&&(*x=*x-95?32:45):!s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZxLb1zXEYTXml8xthGaehBt@YEgdmQvszGyyyodNBSJkgnItCDKiRBbfz3KzD39VfVICZDssuD4IXE493VOn@7qqjrz5OXLi@dPnrx79/z8yQ@PX9178@Dq@vX@5tFnd395dfn651fX9958d@/NxZe/PTt7fv7m/sMHN/cf3j07O7/35tHh7d999d0Xn3/95Rd3f/31@NPnZ2c3@tzFh5/76u7XH9188/bdJ1fXT178/PRy//snN6@fXv307e7knVdX18/fe@vpi6u/frvb/fj46vr87i@7O8d73d97cXV9@fL1q/2j/R//9P333@zu3Fz947Je768P73z2zW535/gsV4cfHh5@9/cfrl5c7s@fX74@HnZ@1gc/2J9dP9gfb@P67v6jR/vDbe8PF7hz9Wx/rgsc3v80rz/dn53tT9775NP14Tv95p8PN//i8vq8f7x78fAv61YOHzney5vDT8/12/X24Tpv7h7/dufl4cFfPzv/@DdP98d/b/Z5/fGD/dWD/ZsH@3nM28N/9@9fHf76dvf23S4qcpdRmbGLrIzDX3eHPw5/Ob55@H3F4Yfa3j@@c/xMHd/N2n48vpHryOMPx7e3Aypr@@g6YjvN4Y3DYYf/HY88XvjwRqwzbP8c/3e4@LrYOt/xTMdz1vGw43mDc3Kq3O4kttuo42dzneB4B9tp@lPbzcV2z31PfXRsn9me5vjMxYW3o6tv8XhgnzZy3cX2BNvDc9rjNbfXNl7cxXZOXUZX356@z923s/62DVM/XjJSa7RiO9F2yR6N7Tx9zTUOwTmPY7Y@ltxnaXTWe9uvak3EmoV1s9uRazTWcEQPLVfeTrJuP9at5hruWuOUa6ZWOKxnKOKgerxiBdEWDNsx6y/rItkzkiuU1pPnmmZF1rqHbQK21/aEa1TWc263tgauena2826h2I@@DVtPcK7TrVsI32GtqeJBg/lSiG3h0MOexQCvIesTKcS32Vw/bbe77mg9ZhLZsQK2qsOVaFlPtf5dk1FrPlY0bwPPdfqZaj3GGum@sY7sPuE2dn2fCtFcd7FOvX1kTRzzsYawGIa1itedxZrtUhz0RAbrq1Zg9ue2s/btbrG/TaCjqB8sUollTe0K63WSdQ898iuiOxDWAlwD1eG7xjl6cIKEEpribXFy@hih0lHco5dFduz8xCnW0s9ekOHstV2uF10fnqQwrdA1Nmt0Y6U1suk2Zr3EV0IlYqpHqXMPS3ENYYdl9iLZIr7TzFpsHFuK5H7I6BGoGJm1p2c9S0dDVteAlSmZZWXxrB48ckxP8LZoenFH6kHCA5/hBMOp@pHGffVf1zIg0feVtH5YNf3zuoVIRVV14u1SUmMB9dh1Ol/j2vObvUQ6syiMyV0r6DSD1SWUkMugHlYnOOWCPhEVpRjL6OSn@tPDnwQPtTFOai/DlQRALzz@pOZRdJPivGppdNkMxTWZwdet8irMLqxzZjoPr1vm4Uga/eEO65WUdX3jEKfmHm2yELmna0zyZ3RWH@WjC2h2TEaH3KoqpXntwGRehQOKCh7Ka0oFPTudIdI1lwdVaPf1FdmdrbIfnBRQ1M5@mE60GvZiha2rU03WCmB6gWZrUVIDev2CfUgbndgaRFQAlqLDI0mVAQbsg5MEB/Bad0iNiI4soEGvyfXGCiRWzsqNYdhH0mOi@tqkuDVgLKLoT1KCiBglzhWrVE5S3woSPzr1slcBy4PJYnl5hQMNGiGvASZ/ZfUolmFUKE9QuiiundSEc9bEdDR0kalRqHkkIrYTWpDywjBvBej6fS/Pogw2Xi4SBDmrYW@jm2CkqqFDh/sK0V4lqUpcDDPrIBuHVxYos5QOG1wUa7FjqoL4A010ZxBa7eRV2oGkXGdj7pXIGo5nuEAAylaKL1VIz0AN7NGXzg5k4VaHSSdHhTC5tKF8KG0aAffg6gIr7rtcRJL2AWVqnIhSqnIj2tJE1kCFnXeZngRv9Zw0jmSpZYxeJoW3y3my576Ulbtl6ITTOa1Ra2cr2hktAHByA0hiYs1wdK7WD@8jy2Byi05Ps6JqqaYvaVhCtYjKE8k8E2QElwAOab6LTA@sGqpyq8BKEfZ2F7yKW5HslFDdGTcgplSQugTVQYVdjQV1Vp125e9x745OLVA3PNFdhto6CvvoPFM1ktqYQK2OI9Z9gjBS9U@Vr/v4ipOzqJMPoBCdagO75CIEfsPrBgc1WAa15J3VYvZSjeIjSzVOCD6Mohu2dq/YbVDfqgp@o0CgRQHeUuWvuFzPYSWLrCMuwSTVAxi0m5R72s5u36uRcbfNwtoNh8Ota9cwCIyi98kqEzG9VFleSaoA9JUgl3kZik@XoqTp6epSsCtZZkrWaNBys6RC89LdWcPCIDYD/FXC7DpYPa5bil7Z3dZDxRDVRZxHasmPlKgeiCvyJDyOgNACCyBSQCw4L3Ujyn8h@FfwAmD76FxaKuqQOqp/6rzpyymy0U1i0DOyolVdOw/1pHY@TyBDKpE0@CuwTEdZU14Urp5pSm//p3DpZd58UWliuwAVxIFqPbwXZEGD8shUCySyqG@fzry7lgiTEebHGgVpzjOoS2qKgR5BL9Hxr/9IFnBBpD86U5GSRI9vIjtqiG7@YBII5y43Id5JmYd@B@SRptn4oEG6sY@uTt3UOlTXCuYoYfhgkKk2CTYHWnttUqVCyaOXAmWTPq2nUUAGirNHkfrZt9FwIUMsE3TjYAiEJEDZQEq6fHWahE34mWgjEsxdQkVzFjmdyUAlOxp5UbQl0ooyGqYXOxuXgCiT07TX6C4S8CQKpq/SfF8HqCBOVZ3SPWv6KYiZZLGiKadJKLfSoTOUOgLa4xBvI1hE7gXXkIMVugGcKB4pBwNAZ5YABBYIOQ6@HpztBB7uVxswmGco6j4xCtZvBrKYKvHRKpdMY2oMThgLSGHKJaUOsjm4qQDkNjEMGtWoq8539mvCxZQSyFg4UHgyqSjpWQ0V0bScEGJgB6nUsQ0yFZIO@vGCsCIp942kWIM0f6NanylaivpFv9t1lxIjoCgO20Wdui6q0X13vi84cGRACWYM7imF3zodKkO4RIw6plAe1G@Jec5ycRPlVLQu5JYE8AYcNp0HjDmtIPi5y0sDMjAHjGUXIlAd8kQwBiEpCL49h0yiZqUnaoYadT3MLZp7Fis9jynAIhRmNcoIZabOvWS1TvVV7yUseNt@jpJAJqIc0h1@W6QPzQ2DraFQ8ktYgjyF45ID0CWz0VIOZk6tEx0YbF10w5CUK@BIdQyE2OMUTUPXEwglUDBaWVKrSpCyNS26NlHc3SMBpSidpeWCiuFO0QurhqpWQ@kA07iMIyVBEcHCFTR@ox@znUlXbx0MTOpQ5uMQSkE/vSItaDaLOZEaSH/dql7LPJaYSqVIw6gCAK/a95sWeklPgAfRxuWsVEKnqTabtC88BQjWKRExi/YUxVd1NHQojYYKDqU6SmlHOWgUN6t2kLQJXpTUEcqvNdKDCL@EZoZbjs7wgvQByQV@QiWi2UyUbPHSRQJgxZ48wdDKuhWC1ka/TSQ1L07pm1IDLRBIkjJb5rZPxO04X6h@w7vQkla6OYNe1iq0PBBC7QUqbfqB1Uc55cGoN73SqQeSaE1yC8GVGwMRmhbcnaOF2QoPQ4HLU01LmN6LU84WWljMR2q1IAuml6hWU05dIyTep1pNWE3Js4nDIeC5/Mv3@eRGe9wc@q@FKLs1OrLFbCSRVuKOoLLNTaIEx6CG0j04KmCGZF/YQ3optfBlksE6qnhW5oa61RwWiU38uFwq1E9RtV2Do8wDlHTPbvkH@5riohoRmBaA@3MQgyhy6EW@aDPrMSXbFIfILCfOlsGmUHaG5o1MJkJ3aIOSWqm5YGOLRdKNm1MWLTZJFgn1SC0YhkJelgiRA4MppvBI35CuQhkmSlJyebhrC1XLMP0VRgAsRqwdZAsXF0axobwwByETUvnCcDDVw/XHpW8NmiVgVL1AYT0TSj7tfkKZPRHO0vRUUxh2XEAGlPgTKkW6LWflT2l7kCxuP3PwbSFS3Rm21B9juTAJG8DqkD@DLkTPiI0ozIiFuKypauVAG@o4EbLkuBiuElxXEYPS53AyDYlR4Cfcpql9tQmkDINTmqAfA751dmuHo3a7433vPtn/4fL68tXj1z@9@np//2K3W8vh9P2Li@On1@2@f8TxEAmx7x@2/TJFXnxw7PaJhqBoHxqncKVBOy5T3/RaDgcp@eraGZ0PrvxvXxf/6XW4xUFRi@dQdiK@SlUdZQ2vgpS9ph0kVbIEK0tgLdL8Q2mJtQwfUopDijm6tswLaZMAzQkpDN9LYPGIUeFkYUE0H/TchBkpUY@ry5CInFG0tMBpzZEJvxCOCanBofZC96yYKENPmqIULZRlKrmLiEXHmDyu5kVMjZEcfb5axDB6HAxZ0OSbikhhqrZPSG1TgS5nHnQx@djEM8pTCfIm2cLy4mzoQRWbJQ@g/GR0QKEGNAQUZRMzGJJgUKXhgakUHWMGVrPYDIKGLWVF8bXDjkgRwVretlRpaZOHkdEbthSaz5DMbCg7adZl0So8hT3hKTog3Ug0vpQcKLOuSA93JZjVFDrieglVlqpXRJ3CfVpmU@aZsjfJxzy9LthrVAa0StUgUlQG@Sw9KAbKKfW9ZRYmddNFCMIP2IMVs6E1OyXbxvDB0fikQna0106kaqAF9sr1MOWggK8Iexr4bI7Adrs8gZdM2mbvatDEMaBBlelTcX8JUmH0ajiYhnWZKDoRBKokP@PdQAgPoqJJSqvoQY5J8miO3gFZDRMr7gM127YKhzp2VtApZ9rTPcw@djyE/LBSSVMmOLBapA3S6ghVYOBuYkqRGgBxmJMBZSSBcNL75KshuQaakwGavA7Ct7RK8iLGIIABfxL/kB7LBF1Ni0@oTw5oDEsSFg5TNKQ98pGmd0Thsa2BpR1SZbQkRNTKH20CBxMWwGEY@QUEhpnCGan7PpKe2j6sGzJwFNrDCMPmpkvx0KXTvlXhaUnAsvuTTkFNERK4QhSwla1Q@9ecugUlYIuSfgSXTpluZTfGuCbtCM8M7RDrVhlcshAG1rDU446y3EXApJYYMshn0gKZxAyLJN8Y40lrohogf2RnWDaWdL4aSo52XxC0WIhzyAwIH6BPmTcQAly7ys2dN3DIsUFcR81IEdslb2iMRdTD0uCixDtBLecHl5W9xjxvyM4bw7gdilOoNBlKEdDoGWi2Ssa86YkQR5JKlUi4aXpcfgxbrvELlaQUak/YlD@SHo1kqHcN8x8R8jHZOXtCP8g@SQERX@WdDGJCShVc5Eu5arFhwqA15HgrCZsV3m4gfKZdDvIxT440T7OW4IuAo1gobf2pIR@pxUh1@gKUwyma0D3c4DDJe5dOyHgwnLthkRi5JmQOGoQRBqxhJFeclfkeu3GnAd1tl2uZWBlWo7luO4HR4UOu1wQ/pjZKpdgGaG8sGaWNNsLnSh3hoCqJFjldeMP3JLlQZhNJI2IwBzMx6Xtt1zLTm2lJBvI5pZ2e7Lgp2@ulnRX0iwycFaFtLvhi3QzXqbJHfCL@wb8xGzKvYkuVr0QcBG4iNCLgxJBHUbu0KEpiZwolinUKbyYRIY0GQ6ZDKUBeJlFoM6EsiaW@LwSUyQze55bi5aTXWSdMb6KTqYpEAehOWCX8tVkWoqlLegu/fNp7Ct0lK3uEfUfyhLOTR20ePlAMNaAHbtNEm5yTGng0hSx73Zr1hGAtATzWZmgLXGj/nyNclE@YQRjFusyIIEzIYjrYFe38lAohaVv7BAFcCo7MHIRO2QVQMuLIxKoGptduaN1Z@QNjhbhgw7HwSh68PpSb@0kENIiX4elL7ZkDneO90M6sk2or8SPZMFoyvFlHC6mJhqICwIOs8Ba0SCnp6v@GcldGwIIO1kVTG/fg4CFWR/fk3QA1im8IG/hWtA8yNEVlNF1YNJGf5SOW/mQPcq8lLXpSU/TQIrYB8Vk9UhvDmxm1bSAsGZS2QEhoCxd@5Cx5h@w3GZu27ANQ4y1XOBydNBIBTBl6w6s73EakLMy2OSQY28tc6FmSJySG5HIYNCqpxUxx0eJuSswSyQoRIs0VeUDFuWiHRMgCUNq3WzE9a4BG5U3UCG@R6A@X8l@lcUKIiY1TO1QMiwubkcJkGSu9hjEmHTIaMPOOZW@DNvazhVr@Ukl7tHplNbRKdRHhcYDp0WlDSWW42ZfQBL6hesjyqD1UWDSUdkVKhONFe13Kzfb0osEdlLANeiKcWcqPNrdRCL6eONO8tWxuI7XpQyg5PZ3DGgrF7pWTFoViEEneVlIyiXqraJ2watpKIL8K5YHGR/uk9IihHePa3y7xOOULUbsAlPS@B/WHKd1abSzmPkSQE9EFS5GER8NA@Urt1RK1Lq1aHYZ3zboAyfE0U7S2bEOkSAWQ20cML0bh9IYumQMybQopO0VFsAi/i3JO7TsPbQMM9XkxpCZvq7b9aLB@FVNyraFJpDB66jsvtEMWGp0tNN67YclJOze0fIPWs2xYQgBWX0Ubqb2jyf6WKD95DEpPlv1yyeALDCK861X8Tcr/n0pVjKJhizU8ejz326VtyuWvg8AJMjY2ljuR9Aa/kKtcw6tBt8YdbqrMzuSw0MnMLR3RDu6yqDC@5yBt5FZkUCfGfhvvKXQHPsz90AyjH9E2Jfsrx5evpBUJNnGN1kc6zmDfQn4SukpyrMiCsQtD32JSI21pQzsKXarPl7Q2Se@xqQTJLuzaNWbIsa2w7GTXRu6yy6aGE0TgXSquTUg0B@gkk1t11kv5kP3YleNqafLEikipX5XFxJ0nGCu0jk/3/SDViVeROKQShWwB5aa796ZJP6mlpdKG6hiWt8G0CMPO/jrtidFeT9M8yG@6mSjv5wxv6Ri2rgEFS42A7CFy3oEjyx0GuypojcYmQn9tSQzJaezJD0nZllnLvi/vg83wJtIYTsAa2@/oooeNze6tGnqJvvAj3le5KWzaT@WezKJ4lr5NI2UmRnlxdzY9QjBs2FbVxMgamk5kAops@RYdOnZGiFkOfyMTxALkStkjJk6nvLknS9Z4sV/S67SGB7YPc9nhb5pK2Rdiaj1iVNizJGcEX08wvg@n5tcKhAmYAf5LclB7d7SpU/2WNxNpXxKng30WHGTd2@9ulb20zVJSjca/ZE1Ug21v8zAaWaTB1i/@V0nC3zogMgUSXpvC@fKiOtnLFjl3r7iD90ZWameWbfE5HJ1qBMSicFGyh5km7ZjHA6uvpVAWNqUFeKBr14XS9GRpE1e6QJrI@KAPc/tul41qXQ55qgaHEyb7K4YEXsNvIh61vHGL/Qeheq8vBmMSsQJ5H6xsL/pek6EDpzq3GkPkfQzyHXhTrpIE8rbq0dz2WqPyyseJZbFmlhf9B@k1IEcZU2gvwVjuChGxiMpVLEJtgfW31I0sZMbbmzzlAPV2ZjRlbThlp/5wJQpCjGdG7k15JENGCr64KmuEZ1ooZkMdxLu33lcNZ9aAibqf0aH9N3a629ft6/Z1@7p93b7@n18Xt6/b1@3r9nX7un39r6/dP588e/H4@c27i2cvL1/9eHVzc/W3y38B)

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 71 bytes (only validator)

```cpp
v(char*x,int s=0){return*x?*x-47&&v(x+1,s+1)||*x-92&&s&&v(x+1,s-1):!s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZxLb1zXEYTXml8xthGaehBtBQGC2LGzzCbILqt00BAkSiYg0wJJK0Js/fUoM/f0V9UjJUCyy4Ljh8Th3Nc5fbqrq@rM8zdvLl49f/7hw9vz598/u3n07snV9d3@9tuvHv58c3n30831o3d/ePTu4je/PTt7e/7u8dMnt4@fPvzll8Nbv/v12dmt3r14@vDrz26/ef/hi6vr569/enG5//3z27sXVz9@tzt55@bq@tV3u90Pz66uzx/@vHtwvOj@0eur68s3dzf7b/d//suf/vTN7sHt1T8u625/fXjnq292uwfHm7o6/PD08Lu/f3/1@nJ//ury7njY@Vkf/GR/dv1kf7zm9cP9Z9/uD3e0P1zgwdXL/bkucHj/y7z@cn92tj9574sv14cf9Jt/Pdzp68vr8/7x4cXTv61bOXzkeC9vn72@enF4560@sf3qzeHx7l6ef/6rF/vDv3n9@ZP91ZP14e0D7w//PX58dfjr@937D7uoyF1GZcYusjIOf90d/jj85fjm4fcVhx9qe//4zvEzdXw3a/vx@EauI48/HN/eDqis7aPriO00hzcOhx3@dzzyeOHDG7HOsP1z/N/h4uti63zHMx3PWcfDjucNzsmpcruT2G6jjp/NdYLjHWyn6U9tNxfbPfc99dGxfWZ7muMzFxfejq6@xeOBfdrIdRfbE2wPz2mP19xe23hxF9s5dRldfXv6PnffzvrbNkz9eMlIrdGK7UTbJXs0tvP0Ndc4BOc8jtn6WHKfpdFZ722/qjURaxbWzW5HrtFYwxE9tFx5O8m6/Vi3mmu4a41Trpla4bCeoYiD6vGKFURbMGzHrL@si2TPSK5QWk@ea5oVWesetgnYXtsTrlFZz7nd2hq46tnZzruFYj/6Nmw9wblOt24hfIe1pooHDeZLIbaFQw97FgO8hqxPpBDfZnP9tN3uuqP1mElkxwrYqg5XomU91fp3TUat@VjRvA081@lnqvUYa6T7xjqy@4Tb2PV9KkRz3cU69faRNXHMxxrCYhjWKl53Fmu2S3HQExmsr1qB2Z/bztq3u8X@NoGOon6wSCWWNbUrrNdJ1j30yK@I7kBYC3ANVIfvGufowQkSSmiKt8XJ6WOESkdxj14W2bHzE6dYSz97QYaz13a5XnR9eJLCtELX2KzRjZXWyKbbmPUSXwmViKkepc49LMU1hB2W2Ytki/hOM2uxcWwpkvsho0egYmTWnp71LB0NWV0DVqZklpXFs3rwyDE9wdui6cUdqQcJD3yGEwyn6kca99V/XcuARN9X0vph1fTP6xYiFVXVibdLSY0F1GPX6XyNa89v9hLpzKIwJnetoNMMVpdQQi6Delid4JQL@kRUlGIso5Of6k8PfxI81MY4qb0MVxIAvfD4k5pH0U2K86ql0WUzFNdkBl@3yqswu7DOmek8vG6ZhyNp9Ic7rFdS1vWNQ5yae7TJQuSerjHJn9FZfZSPLqDZMRkdcquqlOa1A5N5FQ4oKngorykV9Ox0hkjXXB5Uod3XV2R3tsp@cFJAUTv7YTrRatiLFbauTjVZK4DpBZqtRUkN6PUL9iFtdGJrEFEBWIoOjyRVBhiwD04SHMBr3SE1IjqygAa9JtcbK5BYOSs3hmEfSY@J6muT4taAsYiiP0kJImKUOFesUjlJfStI/OjUy14FLA8mi@XlFQ40aIS8Bpj8ldWjWIZRoTxB6aK4dlITzlkT09HQRaZGoeaRiNhOaEHKC8O8FaDr9708izLYeLlIEOSshr2NboKRqoYOHe4rRHuVpCpxMcysg2wcXlmgzFI6bHBRrMWOqQriDzTRnUFotZNXaQeScp2NuVciazie4QIBKFspvlQhPQM1sEdfOjuQhVsdJp0cFcLk0obyobRpBNyDqwusuO9yEUnaB5SpcSJKqcqNaEsTWQMVdt5lehK81XPSOJKlljF6mRTeLufJnvtSVu6WoRNO57RGrZ2taGe0AMDJDSCJiTXD0blaP3yMLIPJLTo9zYqqpZq@pGEJ1SIqTyTzTJARXAI4pPkuMj2waqjKrQIrRdjbXfAqbkWyU0J1Z9yAmFJB6hJUBxV2NRbUWXXalb/HvTs6tUDd8ER3GWrrKOyj80zVSGpjArU6jlj3CcJI1T9Vvu7jK07Ook4@gEJ0qg3skosQ@A2vGxzUYBnUkndWi9lLNYqPLNU4Ifgwim7Y2r1it0F9qyr4jQKBFgV4S5W/4nI9h5Usso64BJNUD2DQblLuaTu7fa9Gxt02C2s3HA63rl3DIDCK3ierTMT0UmV5JakC0FeCXOZlKD5dipKmp6tLwa5kmSlZo0HLzZIKzUt3Zw0Lg9gM8FcJs@tg9bhuKXpld1sPFUNUF3EeqSU/UqJ6IK7Ik/A4AkILLIBIAbHgvNSNKP@F4F/BC4Dto3NpqahD6qj@qfOmL6fIRjeJQc/IilZ17TzUk9r5PIEMqUTS4K/AMh1lTXlRuHqmKb39n8Kll3nzRaWJ7QJUEAeq9fBekAUNyiNTLZDIor59OvPuWiJMRpgfaxSkOc@gLqkpBnoEvUTHv/4jWcAFkf7oTEVKEj2@ieyoIbr5g0kgnLvchHgnZR76HZBHmmbjgwbpxj66OnVT61BdK5ijhOGDQabaJNgcaO21SZUKJY9eCpRN@rSeRgEZKM4eRepn30bDhQyxTNCNgyEQkgBlAynp8tVpEjbhZ6KNSDB3CRXNWeR0JgOV7GjkRdGWSCvKaJhe7GxcAqJMTtNeo7tIwJMomL5K830doII4VXVK96zppyBmksWKppwmodxKh85Q6ghoj0O8jWARuRdcQw5W6AZwonikHAwAnVkCEFgg5Dj4enC2E3i4X23AYJ6hqPvEKFi/GchiqsRHq1wyjakxOGEsIIUpl5Q6yObgpgKQ28QwaFSjrjrf2a8JF1NKIGPhQOHJpKKkZzVURNNyQoiBHaRSxzbIVEg66McLwoqk3DeSYg3S/I1qfaZoKeoX/W7XXUqMgKI4bBd16rqoRvfd@bHgwJEBJZgxuKcUfut0qAzhEjHqmEJ5UL8l5jnLxU2UU9G6kFsSwBtw2HQeMOa0guDnLi8NyMAcMJZdiEB1yBPBGISkIPj2HDKJmpWeqBlq1PUwt2juWaz0PKYAi1CY1SgjlJk695LVOtVXfZSw4G37OUoCmYhySHf4bZE@NDcMtoZCyS9hCfIUjksOQJfMRks5mDm1TnRgsHXRDUNSroAj1TEQYo9TNA1dTyCUQMFoZUmtKkHK1rTo2kRxd48ElKJ0lpYLKoY7RS@sGqpaDaUDTOMyjpQERQQLV9D4jX7MdiZdvXUwMKlDmY9DKAX99Iq0oNks5kRqIP11q3ot81hiKpUiDaMKALxq329a6CU9AR5EG5ezUgmdptps0r7wFCBYp0TELNpTFF/V0dChNBoqOJTqKKUd5aBR3KzaQdImeFFSRyi/1kgPIvwSmhluOTrDC9IHJBf4CZWIZjNRssVLFwmAFXvyBEMr61YIWhv9NpHUvDilb0oNtEAgScpsmds@EbfjfKH6De9CS1rp5gx6WavQ8kAItReotOkHVh/llAej3vRKpx5IojXJLQRXbgxEaFpwd44WZis8DAUuTzUtYXovTjlbaGExH6nVgiyYXqJaTTl1jZB4n2o1YTUlzyYOh4Dn8i8/5pMb7XFz6L8WouzW6MgWs5FEWok7gso2N4kSHIMaSvfgqIAZkn1hD@ml1MKXSQbrqOJZmRvqVnNYJDbx43KpUD9F1XYNjjIPUNI9u@Uf7GuKi2pEYFoA7s9BDKLIoRf5os2sx5RsUxwis5w4WwabQtkZmjcymQjdoQ1KaqXmgo0tFkk3bk5ZtNgkWSTUI7VgGAp5WSJEDgymmMIjfUO6CmWYKEnJ5eGuLVQtw/RXGAGwGLF2kC1cXBjFhvLCHIRMSOULw8FUD9cfl741aJaAUfUChfVMKPm0@wll9kQ4S9NTTWHYcQEZUOJPqBTptpyVP6XtQbK4/czBt4VIdWfYUn@M5cIkbACrQ/4MuhA9IzaiMCMW4rKmqpUDbajjRMiS42K4SnBdRQxKn8PJNCRGgZ9wm6b21SaQMgxOaYJ@DPjW2a0djtrtjve9@2L/x8vry5tndz/efL1/fLHbreVw@v7FxfHT63Y/PuJ4iITYjw/bfpkiLz45dvtEQ1C0D41TuNKgHZepb3oth4OUfHXtjM4nV/63r4v/9Drc4qCoxXMoOxFfpaqOsoZXQcpe0w6SKlmClSWwFmn@obTEWoYPKcUhxRxdW@aFtEmA5oQUhu8lsHjEqHCysCCaD3puwoyUqMfVZUhEzihaWuC05siEXwjHhNTgUHuhe1ZMlKEnTVGKFsoyldxFxKJjTB5X8yKmxkiOPl8tYhg9DoYsaPJNRaQwVdsnpLapQJczD7qYfGziGeWpBHmTbGF5cTb0oIrNkgdQfjI6oFADGgKKsokZDEkwqNLwwFSKjjEDq1lsBkHDlrKi@NphR6SIYC1vW6q0tMnDyOgNWwrNZ0hmNpSdNOuyaBWewp7wFB2QbiQaX0oOlFlXpIe7EsxqCh1xvYQqS9Urok7hPi2zKfNM2ZvkY55eF@w1KgNapWoQKSqDfJYeFAPllPreMguTuukiBOEH7MGK2dCanZJtY/jgaHxSITvaaydSNdACe@V6mHJQwFeEPQ18Nkdgu12ewEsmbbN3NWjiGNCgyvSpuL8EqTB6NRxMw7pMFJ0IAlWSn/FuIIQHUdEkpVX0IMckeTRH74CshokV94GabVuFQx07K@iUM@3pHmYfOx5CflippCkTHFgt0gZpdYQqMHA3MaVIDYA4zMmAMpJAOOl98tWQXAPNyQBNXgfhW1oleRFjEMCAP4l/SI9lgq6mxSfUJwc0hiUJC4cpGtIe@UjTO6Lw2NbA0g6pMloSImrljzaBgwkL4DCM/AICw0zhjNR9H0lPbR/WDRk4Cu1hhGFz06V46NJp36rwtCRg2f1Jp6CmCAlcIQrYylao/WtO3YISsEVJP4JLp0y3shtjXJN2hGeGdoh1qwwuWQgDa1jqcUdZ7iJgUksMGeQzaYFMYoZFkm@M8aQ1UQ2QP7IzLBtLOl8NJUe7LwhaLMQ5ZAaED9CnzBsIAa5d5ebOGzjk2CCuo2akiO2SNzTGIuphaXBR4p2glvOTy8peY543ZOeNYdwOxSlUmgylCGj0DDRbJWPe9ESII0mlSiTcND0uP4Yt1/iFSlIKtSdsyh9Jj0Yy1LuG@Y8I@ZjsnD2hH2SfpICIr/JOBjEhpQou8qVctdgwYdAacryVhM0KbzcQPtMuB/mYJ0eap1lL8EXAUSyUtv7UkI/UYqQ6fQHK4RRN6B5ucJjkvUsnZDwYzt2wSIxcEzIHDcIIA9YwkivOynyP3bjTgO62y7VMrAyr0Vy3ncDo8CHXa4IfUxulUmwDtDeWjNJGG@FzpY5wUJVEi5wuvOF7klwos4mkETGYg5mY9L22a5npzbQkA/mc0k5PdtyU7fXSzgr6RQbOitA2F3yxbobrVNkjPhH/4N@YDZlXsaXKVyIOAjcRGhFwYsijqF1aFCWxM4USxTqFN5OIkEaDIdOhFCAvkyi0mVCWxFLfFwLKZAbvc0vxctLrrBOmN9HJVEWiAHQnrBL@2iwL0dQlvYVfPu09he6SlT3CviN5wtnJozYPHyiGGtADt2miTc5JDTyaQpa9bs16QrCWAB5rM7QFLrT/zxEuyifMIIxiXWZEECZkMR3sinZ@SoWQtK19ggAuBUdmDkKn7AIoGXFkYlUD02s3tO6s/IGxQlyw4Vh4JQ9eH8rN/SQCGsTL8PSl9syBzvFeaGfWSbWV@JFsGC0Z3qyjhdREQ1EB4EFWeAtapJR09X9DuSsjYEEH66KpjXtw8BCro3vyboAaxTeEDXwr2gcZmqIymi4smsjP8hFLf7IHudeSFj2pKXpoEduA@KweqY3hzYzaNhCWDEpbICS0hQs/cpa8Q/abjE1b9gGo8ZYrHI5OGokApgy94dUdbiNSFmbbHBKM7WUu9CzJExJDcjkMGpXUYqa4aHE3JWaJZIUIkeaKPKDiXLRDImQBKO3brZieNUCj8iZqhLdI9IdL@a/SOCHExMapHSqGxYXNSGGyjJVewxiTDhkNmHnHsrdBG/vZQi1/qaQ9Wr2yGlqluojwOMD06LShpDLc7EtoAt9QPWR51B4qLBpKuyIlwvGivS7lZnt60eAOStgGPRHOLOVHm9soBF9PnGneWja3kdr0IZScns5hDYVi98pJi0IxiCRvKymZRL1VtE5YNW0lkF@F8kDjo31SesTQjnHtb5d4nPKFqF0ASnrfg/rDlG6tNhZzHyLIieiCpUjCo2GgfKX2aolal1atDsO7Zl2A5HiaKVpbtiFSpALI7SOGF6NwekOXzAGZNoWUnaIiWITfRTmn9p2HtgGG@rwYUpO3Vdt@NFi/iim51tAkUhg99Z0X2iELjc4WGu/dsOSknRtavkHrWTYsIQCrr6KN1N7RZH9LlJ88BqUny365ZPAFBhHe9Sr@JuX/T6UqRtGwxRoePZ777dI25fLXQeAEGRsby51IeoNfyFWu4dWgW@MON1VmZ3JY6GTmlo5oB3dZVBjfc5A2cisyqBNjv433FLoDH@Z@aIbRj2ibkv2V48tX0ooEm7hG6yMdZ7BvIT8JXSU5VmTB2IWhbzGpkba0oR2FLtXnS1qbpPfYVIJkF3btGjPk2FZYdrJrI3fZZVPDCSLwLhXXJiSaA3SSya0666V8yH7synG1NHliRaTUr8pi4s4TjBVax6f7fpDqxKtIHFKJQraActPde9Okn9TSUmlDdQzL22BahGFnf532xGivp2ke5DfdTJT3c4a3dAxb14CCpUZA9hA578CR5Q6DXRW0RmMTob@2JIbkNPbkh6Rsy6xl35f3wWZ4E2kMJ2CN7Xd00cPGZvdWDb1EX/gRH6vcFDbtp3JPZlE8S9@mkTITo7y4O5seIRg2bKtqYmQNTScyAUW2fIsOHTsjxCyHv5EJYgFypewRE6dT3tyTJWu82C/pdVrDA9uHuezwN02l7AsxtR4xKuxZkjOCrycY34dT82sFwgTMAP8lOai9O9rUqX7Lm4m0L4nTwT4LDrLu7Xe3yl7aZimpRuNfsiaqwba3eRiNLNJg6xf/qyThbx0QmQIJr03hfHlRnexli5y7V9zBeyMrtTPLtvgcjk41AmJRuCjZw0yTdszjgdXXUigLm9ICPNC160JperK0iStdIE1kfNKHuX23y0a1Loc8VYPDCZP9FUMCr@E3EY9a3rjF/oNQvdcXgzGJWIG8D1a2F32vydCBU51bjSHyPgb5DrwpV0kCeVv1aG57rVF55ePEslgzy4v@g/QakKOMKbSXYCx3hYhYROUqFqG2wPpb6kYWMuPtTZ5ygHo7M5qyNpyyU3@4EgUhxjMj96Y8kiEjBV9clTXCMy0Us6EO4t1b76uGM2vARN3P6ND@Gzvd/ev@df@6f92/7l//z6@L@9f96/51/7p/3b/@19fun89fvn726vbDxcs3lzc/XN3eXr29/Bc)

Note: in both functions 4 bytes could be saved by replacing the boolean ands and or with bitwise ones, but it would be extremely slow.
In the generator, the ands before `(*x=*x-95?32:43)` and before `(*x=*x-95?32:45)` must be boolean in any case (otherwise it does not output the correct instructions).

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 239 bytes (formatter, extra)

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
f(char*x){int*a=new int[strlen(x)+1],i=a[0]=0,m=0,M=0;for(;x[i];++i)a[i+1]=(a[i]+=(x[i]==92))-(x[i]==47),m=a[i]<m?a[i]:m,M=a[i]>M?a[i]:M;for(;m<=M;++m,puts(""))for(i=0;x[i];++i)putchar(a[i]-m?32:x[i]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZxNr51VcoXn91eg7ondYBXpRIoCmB5mxC@gUAm5DbGEDTJ0ghTlr4fc8@56nqpjEimZZXBPt/H1uef92rt21aq11j6vfvrpxfevXv322x/fvHv1w9/@@vqjL179/Mv7N@@@//Lh7q2/vvnxy4fvnr36l2/f/@nX5//@5t0vf/r25bvX//bR409fPx7xw@t3z359/vHfffPJm5fffv3pNy8//eTt45@vXn76@Xc/vn/2@a9fv/nm848/fvP826/fPH7q5bPHv7/5@OWz2/svX/7Tn58/f9E//8M/Pn889PbrL97@5fbXZ28fT3P74cuvzr@/Oqd8@8XLrx5P@faTn/72y8/P/vCH589vb795vKIXe/zN7Y6vi714@5e///Nnt189//w/fvvtISryIaMy4yGyMh5/fHj86/GH25uPv694/Edd79/euX2mbu9mXf@8vZHnyNs/bm9fB1TW9dFzxHWaxzceD3v8z@3I24Uf34hzhut/t/88Xvxc7JzvdqbbOet22O28wTk5VV53Etdt1O2zeU5wu4PrNP2p6@biuue@pz46rs9cT3N75uLC19HVt3g7sE8bee7ieoLr4Tnt7ZrX6xov7uI6p5fx6tfT97n7ds5P1zD14yUjdUYrrhNdl@zRuM7T1zzjEJzzNmbnY8l9lqNz3rt@VWciziycm72OPKNxhiN6aLnydZJz@3FuNc9w1xmnPDN1wuE8QxEH1eMVJ4iuYLiOOT@ci2TPSJ5QOk@eZ5qNrHMP1wRcr@sJz6ic57xu7Qxc9exc571CsR/9Grae4DynO7cQc4d1pooHDebLELvCoYc9iwE@Q9YnMsSv2Tz/um733NF5zCSy4wRsVYcr0XKe6vz/TEad@TjRfA081@lnqvMYZ6T7xjqy@4TX2PV9GqJ57uKc@vrImTjm4wxhMQxnFZ87izPbZRz0RAbrq05g9ueus/btXrF/TeBEUT9YpInlTO0J63OScw898ieiOxDOAjwD1eF7xjl6cIKEEk7xtTg5faxQ6Sju0csiO3Z@4hRn6WcvyJjsdV2uF10fnqQwV@gZmzO6cdIa2fQas17iJ6ESMdWj1LmHpXiGsMMye5FcEd9p5iw2ji0juR8yegQqVmbt6TnP0tGQ1TXgZEpm2Sye1YNHjukJvhZNL@5IHyRm4DMmwXCqfqR1X/3jWQYk@r6S64dV0/8@txBpVFUn3i4ltRZQj12n8zOuPb/ZS6Qzi2FM7jpB5wxWl1BCLoN6WJ3gzAV9IipKMZbRyc/608OfBA@1Me5qL8OVBEAvPP6m5lF0k@J8aml02Qzjmsww162aVZhdWPfMdB4@t8zDkTT6wx3WJyl7/cEhk5p7tMlC5J6uMcnf0Vl9lY8uoNkxGR1yp6qU89qBybyKA4oKHuY1U0HPTmeInJrLgxrafX0ju7NV9oOTAora2Q/TidZhL1bYuTrV5KwAphdodhYlNaDXL9iHtNGJrUFEBWApOjySVBlgwD44SXAAr3OH1IjoyAIa9Jo8b5xAYuWc3BgD@0h6TFRfmxR3BoxFFP1JShARY@I8sUrlJPWdIJlHp172KmB5MFksr1nhQINGyGeAyV9ZPYo1MCrME5QuimsnNXHOmZiOhi4ytQo1j0TEdkILUl4MzDsBen7fy7Mog42XiwRBzmrY2@gmGKlq6NDhfkK0V0laiYthZh1k4/DKAmWW6bDBRbEWO6YqiD/QRHcG4Wonr9IOJOU6G3OfRNZwPGMKBKDspPiyQs4M1MIefensQBa3Tph0cjSEyaUN5cO0OQi4B9cLnLjvchFJ2geU2TgRpVTlRrTlRNZChZ13mZ4Eb/WcNI5kqWWsXibF2zV5sue@zMrdMnTC6ZzWqLWzFe2MCwCc3ACSmDgzHJ2r/ceHyDKY3KLTc1asljZ9ScMS1iIqTyTzTJARXAIc0nwXmR5YG6qaVoGVIvaeLvgUtyLZmVCnM25ATKkgdQnVQYVdjYU6p05P5e9x747OFqgbnuguw7aOwr46z7RGUhsTqNVxxLpPEEZa/6x83cdX3J3FTj6AQnSqDeySixD4Da8bHNRiGWzJO6vF7qUaxUeWNU4EH4OiG7Z2r9htUN@qBb9RINCiAG9p@Ssu13NYySLriEswSfUABu0m5Z62s9v3amTcbbNYu@FwTOvaNQwCo@h9smqImF6qLK8kVQD6Ssg1vAzFp0tR0vR0dSnYlaxhSs5o0HKzpMJ56e6sYWEQmwH@KjG7B9vjTkvRK7vbeqgYorqI80iX/EqJ9kBckSfhcQRCByyASAGx4Lz0Rsx/IfwreAGwfXQuLYs6pI71z86bvpwiG90kBj0jK9rq2nmoJ7XzeQIZ0kTS4K/AMh1lTXlRuHqmKb39x3DpZd58UTmxXYAK4sBaD@8FWdCgPDJtgSSL@vbpzLtriRgyYvixRkHOeQZ1yaYY6BH0Eh3//iFZwAWR/uhMJSWJnrmJ7KghuvmLSSCcu9yEvJOZh34H5JFDs/HBAemDfbw6ddN1aNcK5igxfDDIVJsEmwOtZ21SpcLk0UuBskmf1tMokIHi7FGkfvZtNFzIkGWCblwMgUgClA2kpMu30yRsYp6JNiLB3CUq2rPI6YYMNNnRyEvRlqQVZTSGXuxsXAJRJqdpr9VdJOBJCqav0nxfB6gQp6ru6Z4z/RTETLJY0ZTTJNS00uEZyo6A9jjkbYRF5F5wDTnY0A3gRPFIuRgAOrMEILBAyHHw9eDsSeAx/WoDhuEZirpPjIL1m4Espko@2nLJNKZjcMdYQApTLil1kM3BTQUgt4lh0Kijbp3v7NeEy1BKIGNxoHgyqSg5sxoW0Rw5IWRgF6nUsQ0yFUkH/XhBWJGU@0ZS1iCHv7HWZ0pLUb/od7vuUmIEinLYU9Sp61KN03fnh4IDRwaUYMbinlL81unQDDElYtUxQ3lRvyXznDXFTcqpaF3ILQngDThsOg8Yc1pB8HOXlwZkYA4Yyy5EoDrkiWAMQikIvj2XTGKz0hO1Q426HsMtDvcsK72PKcAiFGY1yggzU@deslqn@qoPEha8bT9HKZBJlEO6w29L@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@oa6CmWYKEnl8piuLayWMfRXDAJgMWLtIFtMcWEUG8qLOQiZUOWLgYNpD9cfV99aNEvAqM4ChfVMKPkc9xPK7J1wlkNPNYUxjgvIgJI/oVLktOWs/C1tL5Jl2s9cfFtIqk@GLftjLBdDwgawOvRn0IX4jNiIYhixkMvaqlYutGHHiZCl42K5SnBdRSxKn8PJNCRGwU9Mm2b7OiaQGhicaoLzGPCtu1t7POrh4XbfD3/86J9fv3v9/ttffnz/2Ucfv3h4OMvh/v0XL26fPrf74RG3QxRiPzzs@mVKXvzu2OsTDUHRPhynmEqDdlxDfdNrTTio5Nu1Mzq/u/J/@3rxP70eb3FR1PIcZifiq6zqKGt4FVT2mnZQqmQJVpZgLXL4h3KJtQwfKsWhYo6urXkhxyRAc0IKw/cSWDxiVTgtLIjmi57bMCMV9bi6hkTkjKKlBU47R0P4hTgmVIPD9sJ7NiZqoCdNUUoLZQ2V3EVkRMfYPK7zIlMzSI4@3xYxBj0uhixo8oeKSDFV2ydU2yzQNZkHXUwfmzyjnkqQN8kWlhdnQw@qbJYeQP1kdEBhAxoCRW1iA4YUDKocHphK6ZhhYJ3FZhActtSKMteOcURKBLu8x1Ll0iYPI6M3bCk0nyWZjaHsrlnXolV4CnvCUzogp5FofKkcqFlX0mO6Esxqho5cL6HKUp0VUfdwn5Z5KPNM7U36mLfXBXuNZcBVaoNIUVnks3pQLJRT9r01LEx600UIwg@MByt2QzvslLaN5YOj8UlDdrXXk0htoAV7NfUwdVDAV8R4GvhsrsCednkDL03aw97VooljQYOqoU/l/hKkwujVcjAt6zJRdCcIVCk/491ACA@ioknKUdGDHJPk0Vy9A7IaJlbcBzbbYxUOO3ZW0D1n2tO9zD7jeAj9sKqkqQkOrBY5Bmk7QgsM3E1sKdIBkMPcDCgjCYRT79NXQ3INNKcBaHodxLe0SnoRYxHAgD/FP6THGoKutsUn7JMDGmMkiREOUxpyPPKRQ@9I4bGtgaUdqjIuCYla/dFD4GDCAjgsI79AYJkpJiN130fSs@3DuqGBo9AeVhg2N13GQ5fO8a2Kp5WAtfuTTkFNEQpcIQU8ylbY/jWnPoISsMWkH8GlU9OtdmOMa2pHeGZoh1i3ZnBlIQysMVLPdJQ1XQRMasmQQT6TFsgkw7Ao@cYaT1oTa4D@yM6wbCzpfLWUHHdfELRYiHPJDAgfoE/NGwgBU7tqmrvZwKFjg7iO2pEi26U3NNYi6mFpcFHyTlDL@bvLaq8Znje088YybodxCpWmoRQBjZ6BZqs05m1PhBxJmiqRcHPocf0YY7nGL1RKKdSeGFP@Sno0kmHvGsN/ROhjGufsHf2gfZICIl81OxlkQsoKLvlSU7XYMDGgNXS8lcJmxWw3EJ@5y0Ef8@ZI8z5rCV8EjrJQbv2pJR/ZYqSdvoByOUUTuocbXCb52aUTGg@WczdGJEauCc1BizDCgLWM5MZZDd8zbtxtQJ@2a2qZrAyrcbjucQKjw4eu1wQ/phulUrYB2htLRrnRRnxu6ogJqlK0yO3CW74n5ULNJkojMpiLmdj0vdu1hunNHEkG8jnVTu923NTY69XOCvpFA2dFuM0FX@w0w3Wv7BGfiH/wb8yG5lVsqfpK5CBwE6ERASeWPIra5aIoxc4UJco6xWwmkZBGgyHToRQgL5Mo3EyoJbHs@0KgTGaYfW4pL6deNzphziY6TVUkCkB3wirhr80aIZq65Fv45XO8p9BdWtkjxnekJ5ydPLZ5@EAx1IAeuM0h2nROOvBoClnjdWvWE4K1BHiszXALXLj/byJcyieGQVjFuoYRQZjQYrrYFXd@qkIobbtPEMBlcGTmInRqXAClEUcTqw1Mr91w3Y3yB8YKueCBYzErefH6UG7TTyKgQbwsT1@6Zw50jvfCnVl31VbxI9kwWhreRkcL1cSBogLgRVbMFrRIlXT7v6Xc1SBgocPoounGPTh4iNXVPc1ugFrFN8QGcyvugwynqAZNFxZN5Gd9xOpP40HuteSiJzVFDy1iGxCf1aPaGLOZ0W0DMZJBuQVCoS2m8CNn6R0av8natDU@ABtvXeFwdGokAkwNvTGrO6aNSC3MY3NIMPYsc9GzkickhnI5DBqVdMRMuWi5m5JZIlkhQuRwRTOgci7ukAgtAOW@3YrtWQM0mjdRI2aLRH@4zH@VgxNCJjbu7VCxLC5sRoohy1jptYwxOSHjgA3vWONtcGM/W6j1lyrt0erVqKFV1kWExwWmV6cNJZUxzb5CE/iG6qHl0T1UWDRMu5ISMfHiXpeaZnt70eAOSmyDnghnlvrR9jYK4eudM222lu1tpGP6ECXnTOeyhkKxz8rJEYViEUmzraQ0ic5W0bpj1dxKoF@F8kDj4z4pHzHcMe7@dsXj1BdiuwCUnH0P9oepbm0bi7kPEeROdMFSpPA4MFBf6Xi1pNbVqu0wZtfsFCAdTztFu2UbIkUVQLePDC9G4ZwNXZoDMscUUuMUlWARv0s5p/vOw22AYZ8XS2qabdVjP1qsX8WWXGtpEilGT7/zwh2y0OhsoZm9GyM5uXPD5Ru0njWGJQRg@yraSPeOJvtboubJY1F6WvZrSgZfYBAxu17lb1L/f5qqGMWBLaPh0eNNv11uU675OgicIGtjY00nkrPBL3SVO7wO@mjcMU3VsDO5LHSaudURx8FdIyqs7znIMXIbGdSJtd9m9hROB77M/dAMqx9xm9L4K9eXr@QoEmziWq2POs5i30I/CV0lOVayYO3C8FtMaqUtN7Sj0KV9vtLaJr3XphIkuxjX7mCGXNsKa5zsbuSucdnUcoII3lVxx4REc4BOsrnVyXqpD3keu3JdLYc8GUWk7Fe1mEznCcYK1/H9vh@kOnkVxSFLFLIFlJt3P5sm50lHWio3VMeyvC2mRQy7@@scT4x7PYfmQX7zZqJmP2fMlo5l61pQsGwEtIfovANH1nQY7KqgNVqbCOdrS2JJTmtPfihlj8xa4/uafbAZs4k0lhOw1vY7uuhlYxv3Vi29xC/8iA9Vbgqb@6mmJxtRPMtv00jNxCgv051tjxAMG7ZVmxitoTmJTKDIlm/p0LUzQmY55huZIBYgV2o8YnI6NZt7srTGy36p17mGF7aP4bJjvmkqtS/E1npkVNizpDOCrydY34dT@2sFYgiYBf5LOai9O27qtN@azUTuS@J0sM/CQdb9@N1HZS@3WSrVOP6lNdEGe7zNy2g0Ig22fvlfk8R864BkCiS8m8L58qK628sWuXevTAc/G1mpnVlji8/l6LQRkEXhomSPYZrcMY8H1q@lMAsPpQV4oGv3Qjn0ZLmJK6dADpHxuz5s2vdx2VjrcslTtTicGLK/Ykngtfwm8qg1G7fYfxDWe78YjEnECjT7YLW9@L0mSwdOO7daQzT7GPQdzKZckwTytvVob3utVXn1cWJZrJ3lpf8gvRbkqMEU7iVYy90QkUU0V7EI3QI731K3stAw3rPJUwfobGdGU3bDKTv1lytRCLGeGbk39UiGRgq@uCprhWeOUMyGOoj32XpftZxZCyZ6P6tD@9/Y6Z5eT6@n19Pr6fX0@v/8evH0eno9vZ5eT6@n1//19fCfr7774dvvf/7txXc/vX7/9s3PP7/519f/BQ)

Comment: Go ahead and use bitwise and/or for the -4 bytes. It can't be much slower than the program I used to generate the test cases...

Comment: Well, it would become effectively untestable, with the bitwise operators it runs in time `O(2^n)` where `n` is the length of the input...

Comment: I prefer to keep it this way, so anyone can run it and test it without having to modify it. Look at the note as a sort of patch file :)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 32 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
®1‚„_\Ik©0¢ãʒ0®r.;ηO¤Ā(ªdP}ZÄ=i,
```

Combines the Validator and Generator programs into a single program to save bytes.

Input as a list of characters.
Outputs an empty string as falsey, or `1` as truthy. In addition, outputs all possible generator outputs as a list of lists of `-1`/`1` for deceleration/acceleration respectively.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0DrDRw2zHjXMi4/xzD600uDQosOLT00yOLSuSM/63Hb/Q0uONGgcWpUSUBt1uMU2U@f//2ilmBglHQWleBCBxAQT@kqxAA) or [verify (almost) all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@mFFCUWlJSqVtQlJlXkpqikJlXUFpipaBkX2nLpeSYXFKamAMR083JLAZLBAMl/EtLgEIaxZpAAZ3Q/4fWGT5qmPWoYV58TET2oZUGhxYdXnxqksGhdUV61ue2@x9acqRB49CqlIDaqMMttpk6/2sPbbM31Di0MuZ/tFJMTLy@vr6SDogBRPEIZkyMko6Ckn68PogBFNMHigBJIFsfLKuvD1aiBGKCeBB5kDTQFJBIPFSFAkgJ1GAQiIfaBzEmHmIE2G6I8WAOiA8xGKEPLAgWVooFAA). (The larger test cases are omitted; the more `_` are in the input, the slower the program becomes because of the `ã`.)

**Explanation:**

```python
®1‚          # Push pair [-1,1]
   „_\       # Push string "_\"
      I      # Push the input character-list
       k     # Get the 0-based index of each character in "_\",
             # or -1 if it isn't present (in case of "/")
        ©    # Store this list in variable `®` (without popping)
         0¢  # Count the amount of 0s
           ã # Get the cartesian product of the [-1,1] with this count
             # (resulting in all possible count-sized list of -1s/1s)
ʒ            # Filter this list by:
             #  (implicitly push the current list of -1s/1s
 0           #  Push a 0
  ®          #  Push list `®`
   r         #  Reverse the order of these three
    .;       #  Replace every 0 in list `®` with the -1s/1s of the current list in order
 ηO¤Ā(ªdP    #  Check two things:
             #    1. The sum results in exactly 0
             #    2. No prefix is negative (so we never have any negative m/s speeds)
 η           #   Get the prefixes of this list
  O          #   Sum each inner prefix-list
   ¤         #   Push the last sum (without popping), which is the sum of the full list
    Ā        #   Check if it's NOT 0 (0 if 0; 1 otherwise)
     (       #   Negate it (0 if 0; -1 otherwise)
      ª      #   Append it to the list
       d     #   Check for each inner integer if it's non-negative (>= 0)
        P    #   Check if this is truthy for all of them
}            # Close the filter
             # (we now have a list of all possible paths if truthy; or [] if falsey)
 Z           # Push the flattened maximum (without popping): 1/-1 for truthy; "" for falsey
  Ä          # Get its absolute value: 1 for truthy; "" for falsey
   =         # Output it with trailing newline (without popping)
    i        # And if it was 1:
     ,       #  Also output the list itself on another line
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64 machine code, 45 bytes (validator and generator)

```
31 D2 6A 01 59 AC 88 C4 B0 2B 9E 7B 13 73 07 FF CA 79 05 AA FF C2 FF C2 9E 75 03 83 C1 02 E2 E5 D1 E9 B0 2D F3 AA 88 0F 19 CA 19 C0 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZzRb5zXccWfuX/FVoURKpYzcdL4wa770CAB8lAgSFGgqCcYUCRlMaBIQkulco3861V2vzu/c2adIJbE5e733e/euTNnzjl3r5@evvj@@vrTp6vDu/3l/k8vLne/@P7@8fXV/f7N7s3Xu4uPj@/3tzcfX53@2F08fTi83X/5zf7p8Wn//vrj7v3t0@3V8/Ft9483h9e7i3ePf91fvX21v7rvf9@/2v/s85/tLg5Xb9/sLv7y8LS/eXy4Pf3rev/uw@G5rq6vb49vvrm9Xnf4y8Nhf7i9fny4qaer98/HTz4/nq5897De4A997RfHB772vf5v3eF46dMdrm5u9rfXxwf51c4vbyM/Pcv2HLvT2E4XePt@vfXL8RRfHJ/i@LZ9j@f0@nfvb@7@/Gp/fbz64fXrnqbjrKyfrk4/XX08fep59/LF/uU3u9uPz7fvH/Yvfvti/@Pdw/P@zeX126v3@5@/vz18uH8@Xunx4fC8X68dXn7zt93un4@PeP/h5nb/r4fnm7vHX7z9t7OX3t89fH96bbc@ebrmv//X73//uz/95x/@53f7b/df/eY3v/7qm93u9It3V3cPly93P@4uthvcPTx9eP7O7z4@yBrGfO2b3cX/vr27v91fHq6vHt5cvvjs8OLV@ujL/bff7r98ubu4uHuzv3xzyTOsX55ev3g6Du/5@KE/Ph4Od6/vb7/ef3bIhxfc6DghFxe394fb7b0fng@XL/7w7qnf@@L0Wy6QD/9xdf327uH2OEM3t19vvzs90sfjI/7y1f6H4483j/sfefv@s1/@6r@Pt/nh28vLDw@Hu@8fbm@2Wf35yzcvv/v4@ed/Ps7tvh/sh/0/HS/y8be/njfcX352t3/9w/Pt4eU24I/HX/7t06fKil1U5C7z@M/YZVTm6a88/mp3@jOOr@yOL9bxXXH8x/HP00unTxzfsv18vMLxs8ePbu89Xen0m9Pvdqd3ni5Sp7cc73D68fRCrkuffji9vH26ThdMPrFds7bbni4W20VO74h1hVq3P42kTsOL7Zbb23Mb1XbVdZftqtsQtivV9vlY/zi91B/VQ5w@vz3FNqjt3rtaj7cGfXrfaeBrXmKbpDVwxrsNaA1gzVKuC2wX355/vWubgdgmph@8Px25BnG68hrSuvH26ep5OH2wLxu5RrFN0zbDXHZ7xLUetb24ViPmbXT3bYr72j2c9a/oWYo1eWs51pLEms3sRcv1f@655iG45mnO1tuScZZmZ722/arWaq@lXoPdPrlmY01H9NRy5@0ia/hBKKzhrXnKtVIr5tYzFMFWPV@xInVb9e0z6x/rJtkrkite15PnWmaF7xrDtgDb/7YnXLOynnMb2pq46tVZ2y@qA2BNYPQC57rcGkJ4hCs4kwcN1kshtoVDT3sWE7ymrC@kfbSt5vppG@4a0XrMJLJjBWxVhyvRsp4qenNF9G5aM7FGEdynn6nWY6yZ7oF1ZPcFt7nrcSpEc41iXXp7y1o41mNNYTENK1WskfWGL8VBL2Swv2oFJolhu0rnruzskI6ifrBIZa@1tBmEVIcfM78iugNhbcA1UR2@a56jJydIKKEl3jYnl48RKh3FPXsr021j6u3fl1hbP3tDhrPXSpXrcv3xJIVph665WbMbK62Rsrc56y2@sjYRUz1LnXvYimsKOyyzN8kW8Z1m1mbjs6VI7oeMnoGKkVmDrN/7foVBF5qVKVllZfFUOWA3rNFtm6Y3d6QeJDzxGU4wXKofaYyr/7m2AYm@76T9w67pn9cQIhVVFLYuJTU2UM9dUbWYR1Z5laCV2jqMyV0r6LSC1XWakMug6FYnOOWCUMXMDqlM7YpOcyv9relPgofaGGcFnulKAqA3Hn9T8yi6CQJYtVQFX3FNZvB9q7wLswvrXJnOw2vIPBxJo9/cYb2Ssu5v0ODU3LNNFiL3dI1J/o7O6qN8dAFNIEqHXMMXrWsHJusqHFCCO8prSgW9Op0h0jWXB1Vo9/0V2Z2tsh@cFFDUzn6YTrSa9mKHrbtTTdYOYHnBf2tTUgN6/4J9SBud2BpEVACWosMjSZUB0OwPJwkO4LVGKADbkQU06D25XoiGkR23wd4m1jrpsVB9b1LcmjA2UfQ7KUFEjBLnilUqJ6lvBYkfnXrZu4DtwWKxvbzDgQYNw9cEk78aOqcBXC9uL9cqXRTXTmrCOQ2PozEMEFeFmkciYjuhBSkvDPNWgBqRr321VqXxcpEgyFkNexvdBDNVDR063FeI9i5JVeJimtkH2Ti8skCZpXTY4KLYix1TFcQfaKI7g9BuJ6/SDiTlOhtzB60GZYkCAShbKb5UIb0CNbBH3zo7kIVbHSadHBXC5NKG8qG0aQRMC8QNVtx3uYgk7QPK1J0RpVTlRrSlhayBCjvvsjwJ3uo1aRzJVssYvUwKb5fzZK99KSt3y9AJp3Nao9bOVrQz2gDg5AaQxMRa4ehcrR9@iiyDxS06Pa2KqqWavqRhCdUiKk8k60yQEVwCOKT5LjI9sWqoyq0CO0XY2632Km5FslNCdfvdgJhSQeoSVAcVdjUW1KluqKn8Pe/d0akF6oYnustQW0dhH51nqkZSGxOo1XHEvk8QRqr@qfJ1H19xdhV18gEUolNtYJfchMBveN3goAaVoZa8s1rMXqpRfGSpxgnBh1F0w9buFbsN6qGq4DcKBFoU4C1V/orb9RpWssk64hJMUj2BQbtJuaft7Pa9Ghl32yys3XA43Lp2DYPAKHqfrDLb01uV7ZWkCkBfCXKZ/KH4dClKmp6uLgW7kmWmZM0GLTdbKrQu3Z01LAxiM8BfJcyuD6vHdUvRO7vbeqgYorqI80ht@ZES1QNxR56ExxEQatIK3N4gFpyXGojyXwj@FbwA2D46l5aKOqSO6p86b/pyimx0kxj0jOxoVdfOQ72onc8TyJBKJA3@CizTUdaUF4WrV5rS2/8pXHqbN19UWtguQAVxoFoP7wVZ0KA8MtUCiSzq4dOZd9cSYTLC/FijIK15BnVJTTHQI@glOv71H8kCLoj0R2cqUpLo8SCyo4bo5i8WgXDuchPinZR56HdAHmmajTcapBv76O7UTe1Dda1gjhKGDyaZapNgc6C192aIfSZ59FagbNKn9TIKyEBx9ixSP@GPI3zLpNSZ5ygzFq7ugpR0@eo0CZvwM9FGJJi7hIrmKnI5k4FKdjTyomhLpBVlNEwvdjYWI6/FadprdBcJeBIF03dpvq8DVBCnqs7pnrX8FMRMsljRlNMklFvp0BVKHQHtcYi3ESwi94JryMEK3QBOFI@UgwGgM0sAAhuEHAdfD852Ag/3qw0YzDMUdZ8YBetLSMhwX2tiOXseAL0UHTMWkMKUS0odZHMwqADkNjEMGtWsq8539mvCxZQSyFg4UHgS9QSVoMqxDEJBNQmFEF1CxzbIVEg66McLwoqk3ANJsQZp/ka1PlO0FPWLfrfrLiVGQFEctos6dV1Uo/vu/KngwCcDSjBjcE8p/NbpUBnCJWLUMYXyoH4lSTHSDhqQPq0LuSUBvAGHTecBY04rCH7u8tKADMwBY9mFCFSHPBHMQUgKgm/PIZOoWemFmqFGXQ9zi@aexUrPzxRgEQqzGmWEMlPnXrJap/qqnyQseNt@jpJAJqIc0h1@W6QPzQ2TralQ8ktYgjyH45IDED@z0VIOZk6tEx0YbF10w5CUK@BIdQyE2OMUTUPXEwglUDDaWVKrSpCyNS26NlHc3SMBpSidpe2CiuFO0RurhqpWQ@kA07iMIyVBEcHCFTR@ox@znUlXbx0MTOpQ5u0QSkE/vSItaDaLNZEaSH/dql7LPJaYSqVI06gCAK/a400LvaQnwINo43JWKqHTVJtN2heeAgTrkoiYRXuK4qs6GvoojYYKDqU6SmlHOWgUN6t2kLQJXpTUEcqvNdKDCL@EZoZbjs7wgvQByQV@QiWi2UyUbPHSRQJgx549wdDKuhWC1ka/TSQ1b07pm1IDLRBIkjJb5rZPxO24Xqh@w7vQkla6OYNe1i60PBBC7QUqbfqB3Uc55cGoN73TqQeSaE1yC8GVGwMRmhbcnaOF2QoPQ4HLU01LmN6Lc84WWljMR2q3IAumt6h2U05dIyTep1pNWE3Js4nDIeC5/Muf8smN9hgc@q@FKLs1OrLFbMhCUuKOoLLNTaIEx6CG0j04KmCGZF/YQ3optfBlksE6qnhW1oa61RwWiU38uFwq1E9RtV2Do8wDlHTPbvkH@5riohoRmBaA@3MQgyhy6EW@aTPrMSXbFIfIKifOlsGmUHaG5o1MJkJ3aIOSWqm5YGOLRdKNm1MWLTZJFgn1SC24kkJelgiRA4MppvBI35CuQhkmSlJyebhrC1XLMP0VRgBsRqwdZAsXF2axobwwByETUvnCcDDVw/XbpW8NmiVgVL1BYT0TSj7tfkKZPRPO0vRUUxh2XEAGlPgTKkW6LWfnT2l7kCxuP3PwbSFS3Rm21B9juTAJG8DqkD@DLkTPiI0ozIiFuKypauVAG@o4EbLkuBiuElxXEYPS5@NkGhKjwE@4TVP7ahNIGQanNEE/Bnzr7Nbq5AkctKt6d@045qxUqVCL0N@lVnUrLfmNsKosAZBI99SlsGlpOaR@hlRgtFoJ8mnhG8DNtsTLEdgWYmRt2TIQggflNEtnSqji7jLZQdEXbRoQUbZDk1ih2hxSOEOQWWNWjizDKYB@iurIMj3aidFCWkxuUusi9sHohN5VbU8YEQ3WJ2hc3V6ncEJbAqQgqeiUdxNaj7xZ4s7kEwRNkkBgLlHre1LF0MjXJo8UqD7UVIXAj6xPLvAiwas0PbBvohjMKmoVuyvWtKXsFb532OUnclPgyDYhQQ1yC9Jwl@JCxxgykE1SZw2obEeFT64XPNXipsFxYyZJXDKgqpE30saApdARf0moslW9I@ocwtIGmgbOlGVHBuDp38AyotSmXaqmh0Q5CFVpHDEqd6mXKzMLqUEXIUjPa19RzCbNjIusCMPbBZhPhexoGZ1I1RQKwJRzfMoVQA8e1ul5b47Adgs4wYSMx2akalCfMcpdlSlB8VlJ9WX2arhyhh2XKDojuaskqeJHQNwNoqKJNyvDQY5J8mgOPIxUhDETRV0NpO2voS6UHXTOA/ZyDwOLVfyQx1PKX8rYBf6ItOlXXY4KDHxETHlNEyBebrJ6zCSwRBqWvCIk10BHMeiQfi/MBvyXvy4GqQmgkaCFnFYmnWraVkK9X9Cam2a3GJai1uz7jjRlIVqK8wBs7ZDSoC0h8lGeX5MSGIsADsOcLiAwDALOSN3LkPTUymBHkCmh4NNHGDbfWoqHLp32YgojStaUhZ10CmqKkGgTojWt1oRamuaJLZIAW5T0I7h1ykgqCy1mLOkh@ECA@OxbZXBJHZgyw/KFu6QyMoYdLLE@EKqkBTKJWQPJmDHmE7itGiDPX2dYDkt0vhrqhE4UELTYYnNQ55D5oE8ZEiC3XbvKDYsPJciFQFxHzUgRgyO/Y4xN1NPS4KLEpUCX5j/cVpYRc5chi2oMM3IoTqGHZJJEFKJFo4Eomc2mzq@@P5UqkSXTlK88BrYR44EpyQPUnrDRfCQ9mqNQPxbu6SPkzbEb9KylliWQAiIOxu58dfelCi5CoVy1OARg0BpycZXEugpb6IXP5NyXN3fyfnmetQRfBBzFrOg4Sw1JRC1GqnsVoBzux4TCYIDD@O2TJyExfbhRw8InEkTI8DJIEExFwxytOCtzGHaYTlO12y7XMjEN7Ebzt3a3oi2HnJwJfkwd/kl10FC52AxKh0eEz5U6wkFVIuJzOsuGl0cSmAwUovvFyo1ue1LSOoJk9jLTMgOEakoPPDtFUraMSw8qKAWZEitCRzfweroZrnO1ivhE0IJTYjVkyMRqKa@EjtXhkEH3AE4MyQ8FR5uiJOClUKKYlPABCZGs6ApkOthvJFMShQ7IyWZX6vtCQJnM4LNbKa5JGpS1r/TBMBmFSBSA7oQpwTOaZXGVuqSX8ICn/ZRQOLJnR9hLI58zp1PU5uFtxCQCemCYJo/kBtTEw5Nn2b/VTB6kYQngsTdDx7pCZ9oc4aJ8wgzCKNZlRgSyXbbJwa7oNKOYdcm1OvsG4FJwZOYgdMrKdslcImOmGpjeu6F9ZzULjBXiNw3Hwjt5cNWcInU/iSgE8TJ8aqlzYKBz/AQ6bXRWbUXoJ4cgSyYua0MhhcxQVAB4kBU@VhUpdVj931CjyghY0MFaX@owGrwyZOHonuxwr1F8Q9jAQ9HZvtASldF0YTtEUpU3VpqKfbW9l7TpSU3RU4uABMRn90hBCx/QkxU@TIOXbP0Sj8KFH4lGfhh7KMZBJGvbarzldIajE@8vgCmTanh3h9uIlC3X0n2Csb3NhZ4l40FiSAKGQaOSWqCTkifupsQskawg1tNckSdUnItc/yFZu3QWtWL6sACNypsw7Lb995tL@a/SOCHExMa5xSeGbYMDNmGyjJ1ew@yRDhlNmHnHsl6v4/EcC5ZnUnIVrV5Z4atSXURMG2B6dNpQUhlu9iWegG@oHrLx6VwQtgOlXZES4XjR@Y1ysz39VXAHJWyDRgZnlvJYzaMBgq9nbisfl5pHI21kEEpOL@ewO0Kxe@ekhY4YRJKPSpSMjz7@WGesmuzx8mBQHmh8dPZHjxg6Ba0z2xJEU14HtQtASXv51R@mtFi1sRjWEEHORBdsMhLTDAPllbT/SNS69Fd1GD4J6gIkF89M0TqGDJEiFUAOFjG8mF/Th5QkeGfa6FB2P4pgEX4X5Zw6Sx062hbq82JITT4qbEvNYP0qpoxYQ5NIYfTU9zjo1Cc0OsdCfB7BkpNOI2j7Bq1n2YSDqKm@ijZS5yGTMxtRfvIYlJ5s6OWSwaH8CJ/kFH@T8rSnUhWzaNhiDY8ez/126eht@SsOcDeMw3rlTiR9aC3klNb0atKt24abKrMzOWxhMihLR7QruSwqjLP7aXOyIoM6Mc6Q@JycO/BhWIdmGP2Ijt7YMzi@tSStSHAwabQ@0nEG@xbySNBVkmNFFoyTBfpmjhppS4e0UehSfb6ktUl6j4MSSHZhJ6oxQ46jcmV3tg4nl50jNdwNAu9ScW2soTlAJ5ncqrNeylvrx64cd0uTJ1ZESv2qbBPuPMFYoX18fpYFqU68isQhlShkCyg3jd4HAf2klpZKh4Rj2LgG0yIMO/vrtM9D5xdN8yC/aTBRPqMYPqYwrEoDCpYaAVke5CYDR5Y7DE4K0BqNg3H@Ko4YktM4Zx6Ssi2zlr1MPtuZ4YORMdxtNY6U0UUPa5YdSTX0En2JRfxU5aaw6YyQezKL4ln6hoiUQRblxd3Z9L3AsGHFVBMju2M6kQkocoxZdOhw@4tZDn/LEMQC5ErZ9yROp3xgJUt2b7Ff0uu0hwe2D3PZ4a9oStkXYmo9YlQ4hyNnBEfux3e81DwqHyZgBvgvyUHtR9FBRfVbPiCjszZcDvZZcJB9bw@3VfbS0UFJNZr/kt1ODbb9usM8Y5EGq7r4XyUJn6QXmQIJr4POfCFPnZ3PipwnMtzB@3AmtTPLVu8cLkU1AmJRuCnZw0yTToHj69RXLSgLm9ICPNC160ZperJ0MCldIE1k/EMf5vbdLhvVuhzyVA0OJ0z2VwwJvIbfRDxq@TASnvpQvdeXXbGIWIF8tlO2F31Xx9CBU51bjSmyN1@@Ax80VZJA3lY9mkc5a1ReeROx4dXM8qL/IL0G5ChjCvnjx3ZXiIhFVK5iE@pYp7/ebWQhM94@uChXo4/ooinrECWnz4fTThBiPDNyb8r3FzJS8GVMWSM800Ixh8Qg3n2cvGo4swZM1HhGh/b/12/ur74/fPri3Vf/cvzj6vDu27uH59v7vwM)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes in RSI the address of the input, as a null-terminated byte string; takes in RDI an address at which to place a string, which will be the instructions for the driver if it's possible; and returns in EAX −1 if possible and 0 if impossible.

In assembly:

```
f:
    xor edx, edx
```

Set EDX to 0. EDX will keep track of the minimum possible speed at each point.

```
    push 1; pop rcx
```

Set ECX to 1. ECX will keep track of the maximum possible speed plus 1 at each point.

```
repeat:
    lodsb
    mov ah, al
```

Load a character from the string into AL, advancing the pointer, and then move it into AH.

```
    mov al, '+'
```

Set AL to the ASCII code of '+'.

```
    sahf
```

Set flags based on the character in AH. Here are the possibilities, with the important bits bolded:

```
    SZ A P C
NUL 00100000
\   01011100
_   01011111
/   00101111
```

```
    jnp done
```

Jump if PF=0, true here only for the null terminator.

```
    jnc must_accel
```

Jump if CF=0, true here only for `\`.

```
    dec edx
    jns second_part
```

(For `_` and `/`) Subtract 1 from EDX (the minimum speed). Jump if the result is nonnegative, in which case we are done with this part. Otherwise...

```
    stosb
```

Write `+` to the output string, advancing the pointer.

```
    inc edx
```

Add 1 to EDX. The next instruction adds 1 more, for a net +1.

```
must_accel:
    inc edx
```

(For `\`) Add 1 to EDX.

```
second_part:
    sahf
```

Set flags based on the character in AH again (as the `inc` or `dec` has overwritten them).

```
    jnz must_decel
```

Jump if ZF=0, true here only for `/`.

```
    add ecx, 2
```

(For `_` and `\`) Add 2 to ECX (the maximum speed plus 1); the next instruction will subtract 1, for a net +1.

```
must_decel:
    loop repeat
```

(`/` jumps here) Subtract 1 from ECX and jump back if the result is nonzero (if the maximum speed did not drop to −1).

```
done:
```

If the parcours is possible, the minimum speed is 0, and the maximum speed is 2 times the number of flat pieces that should be decelerated on (because the maximum speed is obtained by accelerating on all of them, and changing one acceleration to a deceleration reduces the final speed by 2).

If it's not possible, either the end of the string has been reached with a nonzero minimum speed, or the loop ended prematurely with the maximum speed becoming −1 from a `/`, in which case the minimum speed will have changed from 0 to 1 on that `/`, and thus will also be nonzero.

```
    shr ecx, 1
```

Shift ECX (the maximum speed plus 1) right by 1 bit. If the parcours is possible, this produces the number of flat pieces that should be decelerated on.

```
    mov al, '-'
    rep stosb
```

Put the character code of `-` in AL and write it to the output string ECX times, advancing the pointer and counting down ECX.

```
    mov [rdi], cl
```

Add the low byte of ECX, which is now 0, to the output string.

```
    sbb edx, ecx
```

Subtract ECX+CF from EDX. ECX is still 0. CF is the bit shifted out of ECX previously.

If the parcours is possible, CF will be 1 and EDX 0, so the result will wrap around to all 1s, and CF will be 1 afterwards.

If it's not possible, EDX will be nonzero and CF may be 0 or 1, but either way the result will not wrap around, so CF will be 0 afterwards.

```
    sbb eax, eax
```

Subtract EAX+CF from EAX, making it −CF: −1 if possible and 0 if impossible.

```
    ret
```

Return.

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 124 bytes (validator and generator)

```
,[------->-[<->---]+<[---[>->+>->>+<[->-]>[.->]<<<<<<[-]]>[->+>+<<]<[-]]>[->->+>+<<<]<,]--[>+<++++++]>>[--<.>]<++>>[--<<.>>]
```

If the parcour is valid, it just outputs the instructions; otherwise, it prints one or more bytes of value `0x01`, followed by some instructions (which are of course meaningless).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxRCoAwDEMPVLNdoOQitQwVBBH8EDz/7DYx0NCX0K73clz7s521ToYhwjQMcNGWGUGJYUPCaQl07TJ4cOtF1X/8gkgmbw9EpcsZLTTFucjYA@i15lJynnNYmV8)

Note: it works only if the difference in height is always less or equal to `255`, counting from the start.

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 103 bytes (generator only)

```
,[------->-[<->---]+<[---[>->+>-<<<[-]]>[->+>+<<]<[-]]>[->->+<<]<,]--[>+<++++++]>>[--<.>]<++>>[--<<.>>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYpRCoAwDEMP1EUvUHqRLgwVBBH8EDx/7RwYSuhLst7Lce3PdkYUx5DBNQ2gaM/cYGJQTSLNO4kqf8TAwr4VlU@0rKCTMYPxJxgjaq2t5aXNLw)

Note: for both programs, the input must be zero terminated.
Both programs works only if the total number of `+` and `-` of the output is less than `128`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 62 (generator) + 68 (validator) bytes

### -1 @Steffan

```
(
lambda s:((l:=len(s)//2)-(c:=s.count)("A"))*"+"+(l-c("?"))*"-"
,
lambda s,i=1:[min(i:=i+ord(c)%z-1for c in"?"+s)for z in(7,9)]==[0,i]
)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=7ZxBjlzZcUXntYoCAQFValIhCTZkESAMj-xB76CjEWi32DYBimywKQOW4QV4DZ5oYu_Ai7HnnmgVrsw4576kZMFTD5iSyMqs_P-_F-_GvScAQv_679__48e_f__ud__xd6_fvf7wzcf3H57_wzdv3_zq8tOr_rfffPzuxV_857883L395td_-6tv7n94-fDw9uWrt6_fPfzwWPXzxxcP37589cNPvn3_m3cfHx-e_dWzx8cfP_vi2RcPb198-_DsL69vXzy7e54bPH_z6mcvv_r1m3cPb16-evPF-w-_evj28Ue_ffGz795_uP_2_s27p4u--OHx8u63T-8efvH8l49fv3r11U-fv_n67pEF_f7LV199fXf5ztun79y___5pPT99fHl3_-a7-7c_-eHjhzffPzy-_PKLV2-f392_fvv06ZdPv7x_f__q_rL0Lx9_9POnt2-e3n751U-_9oKffPzwzbsf3n7z8fXDP_3yz18--5tnz3_585dPe3r-Z794-bSsf368XPTd_bv3H-_fv7x__-rLr352Lv7w-vu333z7-uHZX1vJl_fPnj97drno-w9v3n18SGEf3jw-__Htux8_pPxP7169ev_88XLZZZe749_9V_93TfXdXdd0191d9XQ9_Xx39_T300-Xj58-namnd7O_uXx2-dpcPu65vr180Hvx5c3l4-sV03P96l5xvc_TB0-XPf1xufLy9KcPau9w_c_lj8vz93F7w8utLjedy3WXG5c39V59XUpd1zGX7_be4LKE62341nV1dV00i-Lqun7nup3LtscHX68e1ni5kNtW7yquW7ju3ttennl9XSvmKq73zGPy9Ov2uTfL2Z-udWJ7bam2XHW90fWRVON6H565dSjveanZfq1d56Q6-9n1V7Mnscewi71eudXYchSl9cnXm-zya5faW-7ZOvWe1Oph9zAKYahXrYquarhesz_sQ5oT6dXS7rz3mCOtXcP1AK6v6w63KrvP69K2cMPpXO971SJbv5aNA-693S6hzgpnj8qNlucViV3lQNl7LPCWjBtF49fT3HfX5e6KdputsmsFO4NcVcvuav-7hzF7Hqvma-F9Dnua3cZWmoWhbG54rR3rjER7V7G3vn5lD87z2BKOZdg23pXVnvZEBxxk2V-zwuR717uy3Kv2rwd4VMTGquMse7Qr673JroHKr6IRwjbgFgr5bp2L4pSGUjnia3N6-7qRCiqmej36I_7kLbb1m4as417Xx9F0XN5aWDp0a7PVrbU17fRaM1p8HVXFDFXCe2zFLSGybJrkqnhsZpvNaydKZpNFBSY9VTme3Qtq6CEE1ik95bh4D8XTYzjga9PQ3NXZSJ3Cdx2D8VZs6WZd_LhtoNHzpPSPXcP7XUJ1VDUYL1HigaLaPel909bRU94IWmtDxnrXii4nOGSokusyEAeDixdwIxNlrGVhfskfyt-Kx2ysT8LXcrUCoPH828wzdNt03iwtYrOia53hPHdsAG3r-MDG7R7CLtnNaRp8GVmvKef5h0SONVNtXUjvIWPavwtXv4kPArTRZCG5TZXJuSJMzzUcMCZ4xddiBZwODtEnc91opM3zo2zcqtm4FjBmJ5vBaFP2scP26abJdoDHK5ttU5oB9K_so21gbEDElLBUyKO1yhICubg1OMFrV2hGFMoSDejJ_WCFZOesN9bBPk3Pg-LZWtwWzCYqvmkEqZgY52rV5NT6ViRn6-YlXWB7eFi21-lw0QBE3gLrXz1UMQDH4XJcG12GK6YWztmDQQ2EzNwEtVtSsRhaaXl1MG8Fur-nPccYhJdHg9CzwF7opqzUgA7IfSVKl3SSeCyzfdBw-PRImQaWp6gOm2ewr4OF5WRQ6XZ91XGgjeuGudfIwPEOmOl5HAVxltQcGCXswaMbIYdbj0wwx0hYLwXlK7Z5CJji5gGre-KiWtsXyjI5qVJTGaKdHKT2ywEdYYOkojwWNgL9RlNmmQ5vz_FJzn7iyowMGA6eBrXiVtTgNICcDECqiT3hwqvz5g_JsjzccdLLqSQtM_S1A0sli0yeas9ZkSmuAI42T8hQ2Arvn1HBTinZW1RdouO2-mveT5xYfCstCV0UB7wIGrxr86Vvkp-6D48RExl4NuIy7ix1DeMQmSgckinhxl3DzlUNrzl1JP-SfN3pq5u7MBfQrXyx7Npw-Bzhg9fAgVXeDi-XO0ZfZikovsAzujUjkhQNtnbZAH1YKIEPBYoWI7x14m98HGc4bZOhuJZJhgKW46Zxz1iwN2dGAevmhrXBYbNxkmFUnKfGTJEgrWp7tVYh9ElEGnQ73EQf5MmA8uLqzSmdahBXZUtVzoXpDCwstVnyl1BX52Kp-makoLNXR4BY-xywou3TlvDnk092w4J-n5bogNDCgkQqxMp5nYXE_yr4t-3O2LidXlGK6M9KzT9NHmo9IVsMieXMaEcnXfEhDhU_b5GhYyTA38gyqGx1lODipI1e_he50OabhBgw22ss3mmkTbS2MpNpDLRC361fzwEfZkGTU4JrOwIKypl3mUttY4keIEWr__xPs2hhE_tr-4_Vtuo5i2hUo7r9y0NQzsRNTVJa53HekTwkPBuUEu8ZH_bJ083N9OFg6SVz6Cml_U64v2Vz0fr0piklvtGmGh7mOyJ3B2QYkAwR85NlgAutlrFF_RxjlySkbJHSKV9obmVTZ0-OES1zT6jo9hS9XSXVYnYbCEP_6uJubzBmjxU3noCoh1NI8UwXLTxpP8VTdlugg8SHh56gGtrcQNw-Hto1YM-nmK4nlhlj917YT-nbYpHeK9fowZFuiRPjlsJtbKNkEQCv68bjWoSBs4-BFw0dnLXUokkQug_r7xNmPCodSpanDkKvoZP1OkO0cWnUIcgFww3qMnesuuoftTLeNZjPbm-cpQ8HhifbROlzqmpZQikgryIhpwS0PVKGJF2Y4uqf_j41polxGsG8k_WNO7YjT4Zpc9eICShakwCn5j4CHe7A0c9xNwJ-BO2QR8dKwm_YYRziRMRNjkXKxGfHo5hnEm5aMBCVrveuOVCHjHLKMHdi4HCZQCZzcEoGkVRHiG_ZKW3gA7rS2-h32UggVGrmOlMsUTr2N3Z7e80Ii7QSREoRoXxUDXCT7_MHhgUtuA-COThpNvFksT30nw8Hq7LTxHBW8imOc8ojekJ8YePS1-SGqair8ZTMMAdHBg0Ik-MMM6KvsJAxAX2eEUNqOD0EFBCmx8LA3plE56Rd2oaaw0k2FtRZDnkMDyPTnBhvPRk2pAmFk5Z-QjUFepfdnn7iDJXVfodwrVKUNblOuHSvJnX8vzRN_arMIECBnRkAgLVn3Cg0eN0lPIh6gQZ2bSZg_bbX4SkhOLcckWncOqCQHK1c6qCRwDGqyyQPn_VtuKFDKfiMcNp7ZWxfBccefDyEuc22aYTDB-k5esxBGO20ht9ObpfBfzr2kx3gl7q53isv2EJkMEIoUUbEEeqiXlpMHZFUsBRewf0q-c0RaZprPqk6pGAXzuGfUPtIpdUZDIplnmwuP7DTzYM9zdNeDh-jbIyf0sRLUcWjw2xrB8WGsv-Rm1dkNpZBWy4yqJtuKRqiT4umm2I57WjUWprcvPkxIMTg9Hrrerh8sbsB-talMJTxTMrRpizmZNeFlw4RfDO6xX_ksvJkb7LMm-agBRkTSLRuZylVwtcrUucYBvwyCcitYZctO7cNG4PzR62kMnhs1iBZjHmPWasX6-iunoyEjTE7wW3am61bDo8xFOjEAMfPoarJKfO1TnhStuEk4y5bPGyPYG6ckigzc2XjMgpH5lsrGbENe0Dc0BqWsbEpPpexAhMJHkE0xyBmF_dc3rRNEPILvjDYb4zaqAsB2IzgTtDmhItVBOXDHEqGqYBbVXAZR-TrFbJgTMHoOWCL0kIMU6VKtdr6OhP3MYI0kC0NCQcCxlAjL4p2svPbQcDsqRsE0c5hX5RxaJSgUWfEyOD1nj59TKyK0-4R64iVUBxR8riQpl8e0wijZYkUTKHkddMK7Hn0GFOfHhJZCZIimMMinHGwE5tbaZxt4D6fTGtz-Xd3d5d_lDd1d_MvAb94cfmne5ev33764sXlm7vaT799-TpQ9OmvXuyvmrP6o-uuv4c9OcxOgfTdzuQqxN4ATh0dePJb5T4N94fP_V9fL_7U6_JvBp1WK_x7TElZOZsyR3L2G8gj5C_qItax8zYoimxoZiW-uIHcDEBNJNdknCxcc27Sy1Sm_3SusdeAm5ukdtWuJYOEVhG6aF06T-fxGZuYh5bfGg-aG3g_GobOMtRIoFlzFDGHOJ2FkA0zYDuJELytngoz7oDvpo0mFIAbSZXAdBYTHeoYInqt0V1FqQYYpf_k8hzD4SzFU5FlKa47Q964ag2inAksqi4UF-mSgRx8SuR1RkxmSpNoZcK4lofhLu25ApXOITIGN8u2R5OebYNBM8PkOs09x_ptbO13jXQVD-MyQNcx2s2iKjHz3M-zEG908mbSy_wAVsqpjYu2Up-ImZ0bqzMSOsMEIx0UPdniJ5SPbU36ejAJhj95S4xBeK5PVD0n7KkKUCbAno4zhOIUZOTLslIehw43QIuDt8OnXnBqR1KjtMq805FsHKmV-Cmdml46NgbRHe1B4sX420Q5wg4uOpVFVW1XjCR9k9eHCOTvsTexdxqQ6lEDeAPvU-hnnqGanGNvEVZeiS9huTN44ve0iz7aNyMDOwayAmHTohZGJSF0TsVnUSVO1DLrb3VmKQ1m5Btm4yCawGJe7ZoNGKKALzcTlwXAU5lpiAsrKbm5zqRIzJWoi4tlTr3FWiekRoEJlSaHx1ryeHzf2RKhuTbi0tHP2TMNgGOX4MzRd0mj0bItna21jkGE0RJrIg2AY067TS0p4IApZBJhy5Ma6EiMe5pepr0SC9YZdx3hV2RYqCF6IDoJxTLCjvQpGr-CR9vNAzOgxGEWQ6uTHvKdMaOQ8MTy0bprTogMKD_IlKm4BelgcyM9I5iU3j_mDJJzhocxnFpM2djg5ta0ThuhHOMyGMtEkgyo8tZMfGv3-lUhGkOe37djz5kIGIX2NEKfzHzlPaNERilWP1qVjNfqGsNAKS2xwl3Yx7EnyaiCg61AiufcPhaaRBxnJJuTUmwqOm35qoTtloSGXS5X4h8cQ6cJ2EfHKltxjZJvPDsHU6SMMhfCW9_LecX0nB_LweUE3BIH7KNeSZAVioEOQVaYneGZ7JrU1AQntqwm9W8tvQOvSn7omazYEgcPRwOmNbeHBj67ca3gS8CxdaMxLUfmxyPWF2iosAmOO0iwmKFYYOubemoxZ5m9LGF0M0zUth27oZkgPHCJCs8uu3WDegTlBg6D1KbiyTLAlb3cFqwSHas6XQkhG3DtHVsyKcQgpntiW5dSpZDIERXBPd7UUpTN26aQO8uMgE9NBogW82-_0KYZx59Dlgo8L2LcpNSrJrxQzkIYWDEsrBy8eATyWE1cS6_kkeM9Ocola3xKyhsFU7bRWBB2AE5QYW410l1AqgXuI2xVymzhUHCONk43Rlid9q9MIO08paVsTAWUdYatpasoTolZQuWgD0Yn3CNGIXTjkOYSllcG0v6Vj2DX07oooXZCaMGowrMLjkQmLHPqIEhU6MFltsCXbq0UvuiDTguoUnqNvK4TQ9u-9nthJUfhJV3Jq9ZScgOD7Q2hbtVQuDBLpsu3I4vxYpQXwBVxoEB1n-Jjg06IkCY2Qe9W-o6Y5RnlBjAbcaxOJ8c_nDEyFmz1x2ZszbCDbAL20vnCXTtITDINVITgcWYaY-yMJHZup7UHgLvSKJvxwvaI6U55I2ugQ_OnY98aj-5ClNBLUzfT04oUhD6gFTY4S0Ed0U5bDYXTfcSzWzfF5hMEMoVO02tNRWnLZqMqds9WVbQwmyWUGRmZLZ2JAPWe-067SrrMRBRaTSJWPDmMG4VyjDSlKgLbT3fXGSMWm4xreEPGPm0eegZdt4HWlinT1G1VysDMGGgASxQ5kQaugNmxEqeg_MmtdDeEu8LH7zqKEBrjm2ymGFEyfSH-pAHL3C2JhoDIWciQaABEOyil05d0TaBIJgWLTwO7dpxcxaNLJs04IM23EL2xfKRchoZqaCcLGMThID1vanUQOSZuv5pbo5GzxH1XRy-lvzkw5uAE5bZSnAdS3Ww-GYTMMGWHiuqbo7CF21Nt_al9iATa5zjFe8wHUadWK4Uti6FToA6JwkKl0sQV00mb3kXQGw891qyDiRg-gh5hyFglycxzjQWUFLiKJU-lp8AGLIbqQoT0M8Bv1MG5BwO10rFyxeBxaGPOhNHa1k0AAS49txY9iph1bUKWpEpV5wh2-X5PEqK4Qd6WvqKr01FgKyOLUTQTrXusnMaYWuU8dOQEWwds05gH8W7SLZXzFEjrrcTa0mDVJ73tFej7Jt0xzT6dMGmdOeBC6T04r0sID88enQXXS84IJOoOT74JIeNd6JIgI9CWU2FugTuZn1BMDtxMibSNk0gMp0yMJkxReORcNI2cRluUG6lKa8Wt5mZALG9eEn8747S4eZRhTsAEY903gjoEVKeEZMnNPDJidnZTViLNwKHfoKgqG5prPzzxMWnvgHdsUAOsrIyaaFtFytMmOgkXT9lhlXYoRqA9M4wDGzjM0LIrMwnZWZ4SpZONh5sE3j0YdDtpMZIRC6ZqN65HufHWUX3nadhszm8ygWhMmVrq8EH1WQ83xrzb7y56Yfd1ptUDA1jv1Fl9OSbO2alXD2mEpTAUGLPAD916O18bonVu4Rn3ar9V9Y1tQNjrdEQ38XGDgoaaK9iiTLhzSkjFNuEjRqM-yNl4U2xIL1l0aCkEWbbECqBNICfbzWjqnLafzo1kSle9caYCoEZU3xOphBhgb7CtszSpxmpAK9qqMySAtSMjJZO1LbMCuU4ChEMvnAUjCyi2XBpgkTVOaUjKMlcUkOBCkHXZ-ogj8arlVkayOkI9cbNT0cKgE06CEUsrh0gmRZkVqzK59-zAGAauTheISJbwcAp-s7xwnO3MW3TQ6PIj72So6OCgfb-10oySOSwKv7mpvzNTKX-lcrABI4DPipGqxZ5jEqaeeQfd0G9jB7dhpVW1mbJNEkK22cMWfqvkLFKIRzVGrFI61lOWWEUfQzdtt1p2IaVSSJ2TPA-iVm2gHK2zzDEU_2gOw258AE2J7YWYOpBr-paWhbWTh4ftWAInEUPbVkrea4k5xGktspwOBV5thxVWO9zQeadEpRIg4i3MZCuhV5DkTAjqSUzZPXHE1cbRrcuzOGYzuAvkmMMUmljftHskYsrEedOE46DjXByzbT-rpM86dE8OTD3i_MM4IlGUveVk6Ipy-PsQEkk2KkpIF9zIMzIrLrj-0I5Ku7TRT8o5rVxj2-ID7v_f_5ju8-vz6_Pr8-vz6_Pr__PrT_6j78-vz6_Pr8-vz6_Prz_1urvb_7vz_wE)

Takes "AH?" for "\_/" to save a few bytes

Comment: `i:=i-1+ord(c)%z for` => `i:=i+ord(c)%z-1for` for -1 byte. Moves the `-1` so that space can be removed

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 104 bytes

```
+`^(((?<-3>-|/)|(\+|\\))*)((?<8-3>)|((?<3>)))_(((?<-3>_|/)|(?<3>_|\\))*)$(?(3)^)
$1$#5$*+$#8$*-$6
[^-+]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY@9bgJBDIR7vwaLtHunkxUhEEUUyjxEnBtSUNBQIMp794tnFtBK/vk0Y3vvl8f19rdu6/d5Hc9zrfX0Oe2@psXbUmNcIlobGukxcbKsMreGlxSSkuKpLvVUd21uVj7KZl@GsWyOZZjKwX7mafy1dXV4WDgi3DwQnqVlyoLQHPBsIE5CDUgDagmiO9kQy4CApN2hMQnSloFOLk7gfYIeA5fDjdAzSZNITmLJeikD2BqocHVaEdLokn6ZLtHZ2g4N8l4QPa3vv9KvBfqI7v0H) Link includes faster test cases. Outputs nothing if there are no flat bits or the input is invalid. Explanation:

```
+`
```

Repeat until all the instructions have been generated.

```
^(((?<-3>-|/)|(\+|\\))*)
```

Start by matching either `-` or `/` (removing from capture group `3` captured in a previous iteration), or either `+` or `\` (capturing into capture group `3`), repeating as much as possible, into capture group `1`.

```
((?<8-3>)|((?<3>)))
```

Either remove from capture group `3` and capture into group `8` or make another capture into capture group `3` and also capture group `5`. Then match the flat bit that we're going to create an instruction for, depending on which option was taken.

```
_(((?<-3>_|/)|(?<3>_|\\))*)
```

Match `_` or `/` (still removing from capture group 3) or `_` or `\` (still capturing into capture group 3) as much as possible into capture group `6`.

```
$(?(3)^)
```

The match needs to reach the end of the string and all of the captures in group 3 must eventually have been removed.

```
$1$#5$*+$#8$*-$6
```

Replace the flat bit with the desired instruction, leaving the prefix and suffix unchanged.

```
[^-+]
```

Remove anything that isn't an instruction.

Validator only for 29 bytes:

```
^((?<-2>_|/)|(_|\\))*$(?(2)^)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY@xCgIxEET7fIdCIsjA1eKV/sRyo4WFjYVY5t/jzkSOQLL7mNmdfJ7f1/sxjvV2H1ut6@W8XNnRemWPaO10qGtd2tbGABElwAgUBANZlnyyECwgkQ3NRaShaNCtQEynGmEbGLR0OjwmQdryklOLE2BO8NGl5UQRRD7WJLJT2LJZ2kC1hVLAnVeENU4ykzmJY3s7PQizEPpb97/K7wX@iPP@AA) Link includes faster test cases. Explanation: Basically just the last part of the expression from the full program above, treated as a logical match/fail result.